# Numpy Matrix keeps giving me an Error,

Tags: python, numpy

Okay this is werid, i keep getting the error, randomly.

```
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

So i tracked it down, and cornered it to basically something like this:

```
a_list = [[(1,100) for _ in range(32)] for _ in range(32)]
numpy.matrix(a_list)
```

Whats wrong with this? If i print a_list it is clearly a 2d matrix of tuples, however numpy does not believe so.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In numpy, a matrix is a 2-d array of *numbers*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way around this is to just use a [numpy array](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93), instead of a [numpy matrix](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-926a6c9b68b752eed8a330636c41829e6358b1d3):

```
a_list = [[(1,100) for _ in range(32)] for _ in range(32)]
arr=numpy.array(a_list)
```

[Numpy matrices are strictly 2-dimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/190597), and `a_list` is 3-dimensional. So numpy matrices are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

tuples have more than one value, so they are considered a dimension. So you're creating a 3d matrix.

Comment: Is there an easy way around this?

Without creating a temporary object?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? In numpy, a matrix is a 2-d array of *numbers*.

You can make a 32x32x2 "matrix" with `numpy.array(a_list)`.
You could also make a 32x32 array of tuples using numpy object arrays, but there is little that would be better for than the 32x32x2 case (since you can think of it as a 32x32 array of 2-element arrays).