# Transposing a 1D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I use Python and NumPy and have some problems with "transpose":

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,4])
print(a)
print(a.T)
```

Invoking `a.T` is not transposing the array.  If `a` is for example `[[],[]]` then it transposes correctly, but I need the transpose of `[...,...,...]`.

Comment: also tried "print a.transpose"  which is the same but without sucess, not transpose...

Comment: I've arrived to the conclusion Python is not "mathwise" as Matlab, that's why this result looks weird (I have a Matlab background and it seemed weird to me too)

Comment: there is no real need to transpose a vector. if you need to transpose it for doing a dot product, just use numpy.matmul, or numpy.dot

Answer (score 314, accepted):

It's working exactly as it's supposed to. The transpose of a *1D* array is still a *1D* array!  (If you're used to matlab, it fundamentally doesn't have a concept of a 1D array. Matlab's "1D" arrays are 2D.)

If you want to turn your 1D vector into a 2D array and then transpose it, just slice it with `np.newaxis` (or `None`, they're the same, `newaxis` is just more readable).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,4])[np.newaxis]
print(a)
print(a.T)
```

Generally speaking though, you don't ever need to worry about this. Adding the extra dimension is usually not what you want, if you're just doing it out of habit.  Numpy will automatically broadcast a 1D array when doing various calculations. There's usually no need to distinguish between a row vector and a column vector (neither of which are *vectors*. They're both 2D!) when you just want a vector.

Comment: @thaking - I just used `np.arange` to quickly make a 1D array. It works exactly the same for `a = np.array([5,4])`.

Comment: @thaking If you are new to numpy - keep in mind that the round brackets `()` do not indicate an additional dimension in numpy.  If `a = np.arange(10)` then `a` is `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` as produced by `a.__repr__()`.  This is a 1-dimensional (i.e. `a.ndim --> 1`) vector as indicated by the square brackets `[]`.  The `array( ... )` is not seen when you do either `print(a)` or `a.__str__()`.

Comment: @JoeKington there is a situation that broadcasting of a 1D array is useful. Computing the distance between all 1D points in an array. Thanks to your solution one can do x - x[np.newaxis].T which gives the distance matrix

Comment: Personally, I find `np.vstack()` operation to be more explicit: `print np.vstack(a)`.

Comment: MATLAB does have a concept of a 1D array/vector

Comment: It's not just matlab, but linear algebra has the concept of a row/column vector. Numpy is idiosyncratic to folks coming from a lot of places, not just matlab.

Comment: I do plenty of signal analysis and I exclusively do linear algebra and this is a royal pain in the butt.

Comment: Courses and books distinguish between row and column vectors. I see your point but it was shown in a text that the outer product of two vectors is defined as v @ w.T. I can prove this on paper but it's fun and useful to see it done in code. I suppose for all such transposed vector operations there is a suitable method like np.outer but it would be nice to do it straightforwardly. It's like they deleted a whole mathematically valid concept, dimension of a matrix (M x N) in the special case where M || N == 1.

Answer (score 180):

Use two bracket pairs instead of one. This creates a 2D array, which can be transposed, unlike the 1D array you create if you use one bracket pair.

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[5, 4]])
a.T
```

More thorough example:

```
>>> a = [3,6,9]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b.T
array([3, 6, 9])         #Here it didn't transpose because 'a' is 1 dimensional
>>> b = np.array([a])
>>> b.T
array([[3],              #Here it did transpose because a is 2 dimensional
       [6],
       [9]])
```

Use numpy's `shape` method to see what is going on here:

```
>>> b = np.array([10,20,30])
>>> b.shape
(3,)
>>> b = np.array([[10,20,30]])
>>> b.shape
(1, 3)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to the [np.newaxis] one, it looks more elegant imo.

Comment: Machines are not that intelligent. Even if you have only one wife, it should be declared as your first wife.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Comment: @bruno, Joe Kington accurately answered the question. Savagent's answer is sharp and useful, but it explained something else

Answer (score 119):

**For 1D arrays**:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
a = a.reshape((-1, 1)) # <--- THIS IS IT

print a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Once you understand that -1 here means "as many rows as needed", I find this to be the most readable way of "transposing" an array. If your array is of higher dimensionality simply use `a.T`.

Comment: Note that this works only with vectors. If you have 2-dimensional array the operations `transpose` and `reshape` modify array in different ways (the resulting image shape is the same, but the elements are placed differently).

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I see your point, but I think it distracts more than it clears up my answer because I do give a simple one-line solution to the exact question that @thaking frames. It's not about 2-d arrays, it's about 1-d arrays. Apples and pears here.

Comment: Of course. Your answer is correct and elegant for this case, I never meant to criticize it. But given the question title ("Transposing a NumPy array") I suspect many visitors will come here looking for a more generic solution and I wanted to warn them that it is not applicable to 2D arrays. Otherwise your answer is correct and suitable given the OP's question.

Comment: @UlfAslak, please update your answer that your approach is not generalizable to N-D array, it's always good to be clear up front as suggested by !johndodo, so that nobody should use your technique wrongly.!, the question here is for the right answer & not a liner.!

Answer (score 18):

You can convert an existing vector into a matrix by wrapping it in an extra set of square brackets...

```
from numpy import *
v=array([5,4]) ## create a numpy vector
array([v]).T ## transpose a vector into a matrix
```

numpy also has a [`matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) class (see [array vs. matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u))...

```
matrix(v).T ## transpose a vector into a matrix
```

Comment: the matrix class is meant to deprecate soon, right?

Comment: [Deprecation status of the NumPy matrix class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254738/deprecation-status-of-the-numpy-matrix-class)

Answer (score 15):

numpy 1D array --> column/row matrix:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,4])
>>> a[:, None]    # col
array([[1],
       [2],
       [4]])
>>> a[None, :]    # row, or faster `a[None]`
array([[1, 2, 4]])
```

And as @joe-kington said, you can replace `None` with `np.newaxis` for readability.

Comment: most concise way among all the answers.

Answer (score 12):

To 'transpose' a 1d array to a 2d column, you can use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
>>> numpy.vstack(numpy.array([1,2,3]))
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

It also works for vanilla lists:

```
>>> numpy.vstack([1,2,3])
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: @sandroscodelller, have you looked at the code underlying `vstack`?  `np.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)`.  It splits the array into (1,1) arrays, and concatenates those!  In the process it makes a copy, while all the reshape ones make a view.

Comment: @hpaulj True, but that applies only when you are doing the process from another np array. If you are using a vanilla list as input to vstack, there is no lack of performance at it's clearer.

Comment: @Ivan, `vstack` does the same things when `tup` is a list of ints.  It makes each into a 2d array.  For any size list, it will be slower than `np.array(alist)[:,None]`.  Or stick with a pure list approach, `[[i] for i in alist]`.

Answer (score 5):

instead use `arr[:,None]` to create column vector

Answer (score 3):

You can only transpose a 2D array. You can use `numpy.matrix` to create a 2D array. This is three years late, but I am just adding to the possible set of solutions:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.matrix([2, 3])
m.T
```

Comment: The use of `np.matrix` is not needed, and is generally being discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what the transpose function does is to swap the shape and strides of the array:

```
>>> a = np.ones((1,2,3))

>>> a.shape
(1, 2, 3)

>>> a.T.shape
(3, 2, 1)

>>> a.strides
(48, 24, 8)

>>> a.T.strides
(8, 24, 48)
```

In case of 1D numpy array (rank-1 array) the shape and strides are 1-element tuples and cannot be swapped, and the transpose of such an 1D array returns it unchanged. Instead, you can transpose a "row-vector" (numpy array of shape `(1, n)`) into a "column-vector" (numpy array of shape `(n, 1)`). To achieve this you have to first convert your 1D numpy array into row-vector and then swap the shape and strides (transpose it). Below is a function that does it:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def transpose(a):
    a = np.atleast_2d(a)
    return as_strided(a, shape=a.shape[::-1], strides=a.strides[::-1])
```

Example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])

>>> transpose(a)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2,3)
>>> a     
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

>>> transpose(a)
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Of course you don't have to do it this way since you have a 1D array and you can directly reshape it into `(n, 1)` array by `a.reshape((-1, 1))` or `a[:, None]`. I just wanted to demonstrate how transposing an array works.

Comment: this helped me figure out how to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.... :-)

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,4]
```

> [1, 2, 4]

```
b = np.array([a]).T
```

> array([[1],
>          [2],
>          [4]])

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method not described in the answers but described in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html#numpy.ndarray.transpose) for the `numpy.ndarray.transpose` method:

> For a 1-D array this has no effect, as a transposed vector is simply the same vector. To convert a 1-D array into a 2D column vector, an additional dimension must be added. np.atleast2d(a).T achieves this, as does a[:, np.newaxis].

One can do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,4])
print(a)
print(np.atleast_2d(a).T)
```

Which (imo) is nicer than using `newaxis`.

Comment: Great answer. It provides a solution that is both as simple and more general than the solutions directly targeting the single vector case.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the function in `numpy` is [column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).

```
>>>a=np.array([5,4])
>>>np.column_stack(a)
array([[5, 4]])
```

Comment: `column_stack` does `np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T`.  The `ndmin` turns `a` into a (1,n) shape.  It's a bit faster than the `vstack` that others have suggested, but there's no need to bury that action in a `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

**I am just consolidating the above post, hope it will help others to save some time:**

The below array has `(2, )`dimension, it's a 1-D array,

```
b_new = np.array([2j, 3j])
```

There are two ways to transpose a 1-D array:

---

***slice it with "np.newaxis" or none.!***

```
print(b_new[np.newaxis].T.shape)
print(b_new[None].T.shape)
```

other way of writing, the above without `T` operation.!

```
print(b_new[:, np.newaxis].shape)
print(b_new[:, None].shape)
```

***Wrapping [ ] or using np.matrix,  means adding a new dimension.!***

```
print(np.array([b_new]).T.shape)
print(np.matrix(b_new).T.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

To transpose a 1-D array (flat array) as you have in your example, you can use the `np.expand_dims()` function:

```
>>> a = np.expand_dims(np.array([5, 4]), axis=1)
array([[5],
       [4]])
```

`np.expand_dims()` will add a dimension to the chosen axis. In this case, we use `axis=1`, which adds a column dimension, effectively transposing your original flat array.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments above mentioned, the transpose of 1D arrays are 1D arrays, so one way to transpose a 1D array would be to convert the array to a matrix like so:

```
np.transpose(a.reshape(len(a), 1))
```