# Numpy transpose of 1D array not giving expected result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, transpose

I am trying a very basic example in Python scipy module for `transpose()` method but it's not giving expected result. I am using Ipython with pylab mode.

```
a = array([1,2,3]
print a.shape
>> (3,)

b = a.transpose()
print b.shape
>> (3,)
```

If I print the contents of arrays "a" and "b", they are similar.

Expectation is: (which will be result in Matlab on transpose)

```
 [1,
  2,
  3]
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/python-numpy-transpose

Answer (score 37, accepted):

NumPy's `transpose()` effectively reverses the shape of an array.  If the array is one-dimensional, this means it has no effect.

In NumPy, the arrays

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

and

```
array([1,
       2,
       3])
```

are actually the same – they only differ in whitespace.  What you probably want are the corresponding two-dimensional arrays, for which `transpose()` would work fine.  Also consider using NumPy's `matrix` type:

```
In [1]: numpy.matrix([1, 2, 3])
Out[1]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])

In [2]: numpy.matrix([1, 2, 3]).T
Out[2]: 
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

Note that for most applications, the plain one-dimensional array would work fine as both a row or column vector, but when coming from Matlab, you might prefer using `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: `matrix` doesn't behave exactly like `array`. It creates confusion. It might be better to cut the cord and start with `array`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The fact that it behaves differently is exactly the reason I mentioned it, since this behaviour is closer to what Matlab users are used to.  I rarely use the `matrix` class, but I find it handy sometimes.

Comment: Recently I had to use a function (from `sklearn`) which calls .shape on its input to decide the number of features and samples. So for my data, it explicitly required an input array of shape (5,1) rather than (1,5), in order to do what I wanted. In this case a `matrix` will work and an `array` won't - unless there is a way to handle this with arrays?

Answer (score 35):

Transpose is a noop for one-dimensional arrays.

Add new axis and transpose:

```
>>> a[None].T
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> np.newaxis is None
True
```

Or reshape:

```
>>> a.reshape(a.shape+(1,))
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Or as @Sven Marnach suggested in comments, add new axis at the end:

```
>>> a[:,None]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: Instead of adding an axis at the beginning and transposing, I'd usually prefer to add the new axis at the end:  `a[:,None]` will give the desired result in a single step.

Comment: To generalize for higher dimensions, using the idea of @SvenMarnach you can do `a[..., None]`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#structural-indexing-tools

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `np.newaxis is None`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: to confirm that `None` is another name for `np.newaxis` in this case (I prefer `None` but somebody else may think that `np.newaxis` is better in this case).

Answer (score 10):

A more concise way to reshape a 1D array into a 2D array is:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3]),  a_2d = a.reshape((1,-1)) or a_2d = a.reshape((-1,1))
```

The -1 in the shape vector means "fill in whatever number makes this work"

Answer (score 7):

You should try: `a = array([[1,2,3]])` or `a = array([[1],[2],[3]])` , that is, `a` should be a matrix (row vector, column vector).

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing them in another bracket. It's no longer strictly "1D" as Numpy now considers that the 1st row of an editable array (sort of).

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]])
print(numpy.transpose(a))
>> [[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
```