# How to add a column of strings to a numpy string matrix?

Tags: python, string, matrix, numpy

I have a matrix of strings. How do I add a column to the front, like

```
[['a','b'],   ==>   [['e','a','b'],
 ['c','d'],          ['e','c','d'],
 ['a','b'],   ==>    ['e','a','b'],
 ['c','d'],          ['e','c','d'],
 ['a','b'],   ==>    ['e','a','b'],
 ['c','d']]          ['e','c','d']]
```

Comment: same as any other array:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/numpy-how-to-add-items-into-an-array/5068182#5068182

Comment: @Paul how do I intialize the column of strings? the `e`s

Comment: np.array([['a','b'],['a','b']], dtype=str)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer in @Paul's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/numpy-how-to-add-items-into-an-array/5068182#5068182) explains it all. Adding here for completeness.

```
In [1]: a = np.tile(np.array([["a","b"], ["c","d"]]), (3,1))

In [2]: a 
Out[2]: array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [3]: e = np.tile("e", a.shape[0])[None].T # REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885718/155813

In [4]: e 
Out[4]: array([['e'],
       ['e'],
       ['e'],
       ['e'],
       ['e'],
       ['e']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [5]: np.hstack([e, a]) 
Out[5]: array([['e', 'a', 'b'],
       ['e', 'c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'a', 'b'],
       ['e', 'c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'a', 'b'],
       ['e', 'c', 'd']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```