# matlab syntax of " ' "

Tags: python, matlab, syntax, numpy

I am trying to convert some matlab code into Python.  I have almost no experience with matlab, but I just need to borrow a little functionality.  I am stuck on this part:

In this example, V is a 3x3 matrix.

```
A = V(:,3)  % i.e. A = [1 2 3]
par = [-(A(2:3))'/A(1)]
```

Specifically, I am puzzled by the use of '.

I have been using this resource to go between matlab and Python:
http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html 
However, it is ambiguous as the ' sign appears to have multiple uses.  When I search for other documentation, I can't find a comprehensive explanation for '.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Ideally, I would like to get the Python equivalent, but any explanation will help.  Thanks!

Comment: Just the transpose, no? In Python, use ".T" (for Numpy)

Comment: Note that if in your implementation `A` is a *one-dimensional* array (e.g. `A.shape == (3,)`), then the transpose doesn't actually do anything.  `A.T` is still a one-dimensional array with shape (3,).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Not exactly sure what you mean but I can't think of any sensible situation where `A(2:3)` is equal to `A(2:3)'`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I'm talking about numpy arrays.  In numpy, the transpose operation simply reverses the dimensions of the array.  If the array has only one dimension, the transpose is a "no op"--it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Hmm in fact `A(2:3)` is 2x1 so for datatype `array` the transpose would indeed not make sense as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885503/numpy-transpose-not-giving-expected-result Perhaps using datatype `matrix` in numpy would make for a better translation. (Actually this is the word mentioned in the question)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I think you're right.  I think that the transpose is unnecessary in Python, because array([1,2]) is the same as its transpose.  I think that part of the code is unnecessary in my Python translation.  In this case, I don't think it needs to be in matrix form per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `a.conj().transpose()`  for Matlab's transpose (`a'`)

and `a.transpose()` for Matlab's non-conjugate transpose (`a.'` or `transpose(a)`)

Comment: A(3:2) is a single value, so I didn't think that transpose made sense.   A = [ 0.08390008 -0.58820993 -0.57735027 ]  Thanks!

Comment: first it is `A(2:3)` in your question. second, this outputs two values `[A(2) A(3)]`. Third, the transpose is then `transpose([A(2) A(3)])` (i.e. a row vector becomes a column vector etc)

Comment: Ok, I see.  In Python indexing is not inclusive of the last element, and I didn't realize that this was not the case in matlab.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's just to return the transpose of the matrix.

In python using numpy, you can do the following:

```
a.T
a.transpose()
```

Both will return the same result.