# How do you fix inconsistent numbers of samples when using GaussianNB()?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

How do you fix inconsistent numbers of samples when using GaussianNB()? Also, is it possible for input pandas dataframe as arguments for model.fit function?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `GaussianNB` is expecting `weather` to be in the shape `(n_samples, n_features)`.  You currently have it as a one-dimensional array, so `GaussianNB` is interpreting it as a 1 sample with 14 features.

To convert to the right shape, you can use `weather[:,None]` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885718/3339965) answer.  So, the following should do the trick:

```
model.fit(weather[:,None], play)
```

Comment: No problem.  Also, looking at your code, note that you can just do `play = df_numeric.play.values` to get a numpy array from a dataframe column.