# NumPy hstack throws "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions?"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
data = [['297348640', 'Y', '12', 'Y'],
       ['300737722','Y', '1', 'Y'],
       ['300074407', 'Y',  '1', 'N']]
```

I want to convert this into a NumPy array so I did:

```
data = np.array(data)
```

The above is working fine.

Now I have two lists, say

```
a = [0,2,6]
b = [21,21,9]
```

I have to append these at last of my previous list:

```
data = [['297348640', 'Y', '12', 'Y', 0, 21],
       ['300737722','Y', '1', 'Y', 2, 21],
       ['300074407', 'Y',  '1', 'N', 6, 9]]
```

I tried this but its giving me wrong dimension error

```
a = np.array([a])
b = np.array([b])

data = np.hstack(data,(a))
data = np.hstack(data,(b))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: `hstack(data, (a))` did not give you that error message.  It complains about the number of arguments, not the dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution, but instead of passing `dtype=object`, you can be more explicit by passing `data`'s dtype:

```
data = np.array([['297348640', 'Y', '12', 'Y'],
                 ['300737722','Y', '1', 'Y'],
                 ['300074407', 'Y',  '1', 'N']])

a = [0,2,6]
b = [21,21,9]

a = np.array(a, dtype=data.dtype)
b = np.array(b, dtype=data.dtype)

data = np.hstack((data, a[:, None], b[:, None]))
```

The first argument to `np.hstack` is a *sequence of arrays*.  Right now, you are passing `np.hstack(data,(a))`, which actually gets parsed as two arguments.  Adding an additional set of parantheses brings `data` and `a` (and `b`) into one sequence (a tuple).

And lastly as for the indexing: [In numpy, what does selection by [:,None] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37867354/7954504).  This is mimicking `np.reshape()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `data` array is an array of strings, which means that column stacking integer columns will result in those being coerced to strings.

So, to prevent that, convert `data` to astype during the column stacking.

Furthermore, the dimensions of `a` and `b` must match up in some manner. For column stacking, they need to be column vectors of the same height as `data`, so that the stacking can be done. For that, you can use `np.reshape.

Finally, for the stacking, `np.hstack`/`np.column_stack`/`np.concatenate` all work.

```
np.concatenate(
   (data.astype(object), np.reshape(a, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(b, (-1, 1))), 
   axis=1
)
```

Or,

```
np.column_stack(
   (data.astype(object), np.reshape(a, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(b, (-1, 1)))
)
```

Or,

```
np.hstack(
   (data.astype(object), np.reshape(a, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(b, (-1, 1)))
)
```

```
array([['297348640', 'Y', '12', 'Y', 0, 21],
       ['300737722', 'Y', '1', 'Y', 2, 21],
       ['300074407', 'Y', '1', 'N', 6, 9]], dtype=object)
```