# Select rows that fall betwen ranges defined in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I get the rows of a dataframe that fit between the ranges of another dataframe? For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,1),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,2),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,3),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,2,5)
    ]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'from_date': [pd.Timestamp(2019,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1)],
    'to_date': [pd.Timestamp(2019,1,2), pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1)]
})
```

Data:

```
> df1
    date
0   2019-01-01   <- I want this
1   2019-01-02   <- and this
2   2019-01-03   
3   2019-02-01   <- and this
4   2019-02-05

> df2
    from_date   to_date
0   2019-01-01  2019-01-02
1   2019-02-01  2019-02-01
```

The ranges can overlap each other. I want find all rows in `df1` that fall between *any* of the ranges in `df2`. I tried:

```
df1[df1['date'].between(df2['from_date'], df2['to_date'])]
```

But that resulted in an error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `numpy` broadcast

```
s2_1=df2.from_date.values
s2_2=df2.to_date.values
s1=df1.values[:,None]
df1[np.any((s1>=s2_1)&(s1<=s2_2),-1)]
Out[35]: 
        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-02
3 2019-02-01
```

Comment: Can you explain how broadcasting work in this case? `s1` is an array of length 5 while `s2_1` and `s2_2` are arrays of length 2.

Comment: @MikeHenderson https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html, check with this

Comment: @MikeHenderson also, this is more like do a for loop , like `[df2.from_date.values<x for x in df1.values ]` if that is still not clear, just let me know :-)

Comment: @MikeHenderson also you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867354/in-numpy-what-does-selection-by-none-do

Comment: Thanks , I have some lingering questions about the broadcasting rule in Numpy but that's material for another SO question

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

1) Create an array of dates using list comprehension, [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

2) Simple [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on `df1` using this array of dates and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
# step 1
dates = np.hstack([pd.date_range(s, e) for s, e in zip(df2['from_date'], df2['to_date'])])

# Step 2
df1[df1.date.isin(dates)]

        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-02
3 2019-02-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way which is not advised for large dataframes is to create a cartesian product and filter the results:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,1),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,2),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,1,3),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1),
        pd.Timestamp(2019,2,5)
    ]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'from_date': [pd.Timestamp(2019,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1)],
    'to_date': [pd.Timestamp(2019,1,2), pd.Timestamp(2019,2,1)]
})

df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_datetime)

df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_datetime)

df_out = df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1))\
            .query('from_date <= date <= to_date')

df_out
```

Output:

```
        date  key  from_date    to_date
0 2019-01-01    1 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
2 2019-01-02    1 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
7 2019-02-01    1 2019-02-01 2019-02-01
```