# Numpy operator for each vector element with matrix individual row multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Is there a numpy operator that will result in the individual vector element multiplying with the corresponding matrix row?

For e.g.,

```py
    import numpy
    a,b=numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

When I multiply a and b, I want the result to be

```
[[1,2,3,4],[10,12,14,16]]
```

where each vector element is multiplied with the corresponding matrix row elements.

I know how to implement this using loops, but I just wanted to know whether an in-built function exists in numpy for this, especially when b is an **extremely large, but sparse matrix**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `multiply` like the following:

```
import numpy
a,b=numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
print(numpy.multiply(a,b.T).T)
# [[ 1  2  3  4]
# [10 12 14 16]]
```

Other option is to use `*` and transpose like the following:

```
import numpy
a,b=numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
print(a*b.T)
# [[ 1 10]
# [ 2 12]
# [ 3 14]
# [ 4 16]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but can you expand the answer to include for large sparse matrices as well, like I asked in the question?

Comment: @YourIDE Please add a sample of the input and the desired output to the body of your question

Comment: I was referring to a similar method as in scipy.sparse, but I guess this will do since its just a vector with matrix multiplication.

Also, in the 2nd method, it should be (a*b.T).T
Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a[:,None]*b
```

This should be fairly fast with no extra calculation cost.

output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [10 12 14 16]]
```

Comment: The `newaxis` option is also very elegant, I would add the following link to the reader https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867354/in-numpy-what-does-selection-by-none-do