# How could this matrix / vector dot multiplication be possible in numpy.linalg module?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The code as below...

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b
array([5, 6])
>>> A.dot(b)   # <------- this is not possible in math
array([17, 39]) # <------ and the result should be 2x1 matrix instead of 1x2 matrix.
>>> A.dot(b.T) # <------- this is a bit better
array([17, 39]) # <------ but the result is still not well formed. 
>>>
```

Comment: Just think of a one-dimensional vector (like `b`) as a column vector, and everything is fine.  Since `b` has only one dimension, it kund of doesn't matter whether it's a row or a column.  That's why `b.T` is the same as `b`.

Comment: All of this is documented perfectly well in the [`np.dot` docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: I ran in this problem the other month. The only thing that's somewhat better in Matlab (as much as it hurts to admit :P). I use `reshape` to change vectors to column/row ones as appropriate and store them in default configuration.

Comment: The behavior is fully consistent with being a tensor product. A_ij b_j. It's not "better" in Matlab, it's just that Matlab does not have 1D tensors.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `np.ndarray` to store the data instead of `matrix`, numpy always intends to store data in **minimal dimension** (don't remember where the doc says that). That's why `b.T` changes nothing:

```
In [136]: b
Out[136]: array([5, 6])

In [137]: b.T
Out[137]: array([5, 6])

In [138]: b.T.shape
Out[138]: (2,)

In [139]: b.shape
Out[139]: (2,)
```

if you want `b.shape` be (2,1), use `np.newaxis` or `None` to slice it:

```
In [140]: bb=b[:,None]

In [141]: bb
Out[141]: 
array([[5],
       [6]])

In [142]: bb.shape
Out[142]: (2, 1)
```

then everything will looks right:

```
In [143]: a.dot(bb)
Out[143]: 
array([[17],
       [39]])

In [144]: a.dot(bb).shape
Out[144]: (2, 1)
```

this link may help: [python-numpy-transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/python-numpy-transpose)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `numpy.matrix` in order to get correct matrix mathematical behaviour:

```
In [2]: import numpy

In [3]: A = numpy.matrix('[1 2; 3 4]')

In [4]: A
Out[4]: 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])

In [5]: b = numpy.matrix('[5 6]')

In [6]: b
Out[6]: matrix([[5, 6]])

In [7]: A.dot(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2a3d67ed3e0f> in <module>()
----> 1 A.dot(b)

ValueError: objects are not aligned

In [8]: A.dot(b.transpose())
Out[8]: 
matrix([[17],
        [39]])
```

You'll also get overloaded multiplication operators for `numpy.matrix`:

```
In [9]: A * b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e4962082e335> in <module>()
----> 1 A * b

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.pyc in __mul__(self, other)
    339         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    340             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 341             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    342         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    343             return N.dot(self, other)

ValueError: objects are not aligned

In [10]: A * b.transpose()
Out[10]: 
matrix([[17],
        [39]])
```

See also: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy.matrix

Comment: But the scipy reference doc(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/scipy-ref.pdf) says "*...Despite its convenience, the use of the numpy.matrix class is discouraged, since it adds nothing that cannot be accomplished with 2D numpy.ndarray objects...*". I simply cannot believe they ignore this apparent bug.

Comment: @smwikipedia not a bug but a feature

Comment: `np.matrix` is evil. It throws several of NumPy's conventions overboard and causes all kinds of trouble for library authors (including yours truly).