# Problems on how to transpose single column data in python

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I created a text file called 'column.txt' containing the following data:

1
2
3
4
9
8

Then I wrote the code below to transpose my data to a single-row text file.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.loadtxt('column.txt')
z=x.T 
y=x.transpose()
np.savetxt('row.txt',y, fmt='%i')
```

I tried two different ways - using matrix multiplication (the commented line in my code) and using transpose command. The problem was the output was exactly the same as the input!

Afterwards, I added another column to the input file, ran the code and surprisingly this time the output was completely fine (The output contained two rows!)

So my question is:

Is there anyway to transpose a single column file to a single row one? If yes, could you please describe how?

Comment: Did you read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to transpose data and change the shape of your array like the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr=np.loadtxt('column.txt')
>>> arr
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  9.,  8.])
>>> arr.shape
(6,)
>>> arr=arr.reshape(6,1)
>>> arr
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 8.]])
```

or you can just give the number of an array dimension as an input to the [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function

```
>>> np.loadtxt('column.txt', ndmin=2)
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 8.]])
```

But if you want to convert a single column to a single row and write it into a file just you need to do as following

```
>>> parr=arr.reshape(1,len(arr))
np.savetxt('column.txt',parr, fmt='%i')
```

Comment: Also, you dont need to know the number of rows. You can just `.reshape(-1, 1)` which means "1 column, as many rows as it takes"

Answer (score 2):

If your input data only consists of a single column, `np.loadtxt()` will return an one-dimensional array.  Transposing basically means to reverse the order of the axes.  For a one-dimensional array with only a single axis, this is a no-op.  You can convert the array into a two-dimensional array in many different ways, and transposing will work as expected for the two-dimensional array, e.g.

```
x = np.atleast_2d(np.loadtxt('column.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the transpose of a 1D array is the same as itself, as there is no other dimension to transpose to.

You could try adding a 2nd dimension by doing this,

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [9], [8]])
>>> x.T
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8]])
```