# Numpy column and row vectors

Tags: python, numpy

Why is it in `numpy` possible to multiply a `2x2` matrix by a `1x2` row vector?

```
import numpy as np

I = np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
x = np.array([2.0,3.0])

In: I * x
Out: array([[ 2.,  0.], [ 0.,  3.]])
```

Transposing `x` does also make no sense. A row vector stays a row vector?

```
In: x.T
Out: array([ 2.,  3.])
```

From a mathematical point of view the representation is very confusing.

Comment: In computer there shouldn't be a difference between 1x2 array and 2x1 array, They're just an array. Now if you want the dot product, I beleive it's in numpy (or scipy)

Comment: You have two questions: first, `*` is element-wise multipication. Broadcasting rules allow differently-shaped arrays to be mutliplied in this way. An explanation for your second question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array

Comment: np product is equal to np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]) * np.array([[2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0]])

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numpy arrays are *not* vectors. Or matrices for that matters. They're arrays.

They can be *used* to represent vectors, matrices, tensors or anything you want. The genius of numpy however is to represent *arrays*, and let the user decide on their meaning.

One operation defined on arrays is the (termwise) multiplication. In addition, broadcasting lets you operate on arrays of different shapes by 'extending' it in the missing dimensions, so your multiplication is really the (termwise) multiplication of:

```
[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]] * [[2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0]]
```

If you want to use the dot product, in the matricial sense, you should use the `.dot` method, which does exactly that: interpret its inputs as vectors/matrices/tensors, and do a dot product.

Answer (score 2):

If you check shape of you `x` you will see (2,) which means numpy array:

```
 In [58]: x.shape
 Out[58]: (2,)
```

If you need 1x2 vector you could use `reshape`:

```
x_vec = x.reshape(2,1)
In [64]: x_vec.shape
Out[64]: (2, 1)
```

Then you could use numpy [`dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) method for multiplication:

```
 In [68]: I.dot(x_vec)
 Out[68]:
 array([[ 2.],
       [ 3.]])
```

But `dot` also works without reshaping:

```
 In [69]: I.dot(x)
 Out[69]: array([ 2.,  3.])
```

You also could use [`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) to do that:

```
In [73]: np.matmul(I, x_vec)
Out[73]:
array([[ 2.],
       [ 3.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3.5 you can use the `@` operator.

```
In [2]: I@x
Out[2]: array([ 2.,  3.])
```

Comment: equivalent of matmul in python 2.x (>2.6)