# vector transposition with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, vector, transpose

I would like to know how to correctly transpose a vector. Since my implementation does not work, apparently.
Here what I do.

```
import numpy as np
weights = np.random.random(3)

weights.shape
(3,)
```

If I do the transpose:

```
np.transpose(weights)
np.transpose(weights).shape
(3,)
```

Thus, why my dimensions of weights do not change? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, Paulo. I read that post, but I cannot get its meaning or solution. Since, I think my problem is closer to this one, but still I do not know how to implement the brackets there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.transpose(weights[np.newaxis])
```

Or maybe, a simpler manner:

```
weights[np.newaxis].T
```

However, as pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array), you must think if you have good reasons to transpose it this way, since a transposed 1D vector is still a 1D vector.