# understand numpy.dot with N-d array and 1-d array

Tags: python, numpy

**To who voted to close because of unclear what I'm asking, here are the questions in my post:**

1. Can anyone tell me what's the result of `y`?
2. Is there anything called sum product in Mathematics?
3. Is `x` subject to broadcasting?
4. Why is `y` a column/row vector?
5. What if `x=np.array([[7],[2],[3]])`?

```
w=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
x=np.array([7,2,3])
y=np.dot(w,x)
```

Can anyone tell me what's the result of `y`?

[image]
I deliberately Mosaic the screenshot so that you pretend you are in a test and cannot run python to get the result.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot says

> If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over
>   the last axis of a and b.

Is there anything called **sum product** in Mathematics?

Is `x` subject to broadcasting?

Why is `y` a column/row vector?

What if `x=np.array([[7],[2],[3]])`?

Comment: some of the products.  If it helps think of `x` as (3,1) column matrix and dio the high school matrix product.  Or imagine an inner product of each row of `w` with `x`.

Comment: 1) Running that code gives the result of `y` immediately. 2) Googling "what is sum product" gives answer to that immediately. Questions 3 and 4 I don't get. Question 5 can be answered as easy as 1.

Comment: See also the recent https://stackoverflow.com/q/54160155

Comment: oops - I should have written `sum of the products`. The docs do say that for 2 1d arrays the result is the inner product.Broadcasting rules don't apply in `dot`

Answer (score 1):

`np.dot` is nothing but **matrix multiplication** if the dimensions match for multiplication (i.e. w is 3x3 and x is 1x3, so matrix multiplication of WX cannot be made but XW is okay). ***In first case:***

```
>>> w=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> x=np.array([7,2,3])
>>> w.shape
(3, 3)
>>> x.shape # 1d vector
(3, )
```

So in this case it returns the **inner product** of each row of W with X:

```
>>> [np.dot(ww,x) for ww in w]
[20, 56, 92]
>>> np.dot(w,x)
array([20, 56, 92]) # as they are both same
```

change the order

```
>>> y = np.dot(x,w) # matrix mult as usual
>>> y
array([36, 48, 60])
```

***In second case:***

```
>>> x=np.array([[7],[2],[3]])
>>> x.shape
(3, 1)
>>> y = np.dot(w,x) # matrix mult
>>> y
array([[20],
       [56],
       [92]])
```

However, this time dimensions does not match for both multiplication (3x1,3x3) and inner product (1x1,1x3) so it raises error.

```
>>> y = np.dot(x,w)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-110-dcddcf3bedd8>", line 1, in <module>
    y = np.dot(x,w)

ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,3) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question is unclear, but rather overly pedantic.

For example, why are you puzzled by `sum product` in this nD by 1d case, when the docs use `inner product` for the 1d by 1d case, and `matrix product` in the 2d by 2d case?  Give yourself some freedom to read it as `sum of the products`, as done in the inner product.

To make your example clearer, make `w` rectangular, to better distinguish row actions from column ones:

```
In [168]: w=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
     ...: x=np.array([7,2,3])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [169]: w.shape
Out[169]: (2, 3)
In [170]: x.shape
Out[170]: (3,)
```

The `dot` and its equivalent `einstein` notation:

```
In [171]: np.dot(w,x)
Out[171]: array([20, 56])
In [172]: np.einsum('ij,j->i',w,x)
Out[172]: array([20, 56])
```

The `sum of the products` is being done on the repeated `j` dimension, without summation on `i`.

We can do the same thing with broadcasted elementwise multiplication:

```
In [173]: (w*x[None,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[173]: array([20, 56])
```

While this equivalent operation does use broadcasting, it's better not to think of `dot` in those terms.

`matmul` gives another description of the same action, adding a dimension to `x` to form a 2d by 2d matrix product, followed by a squeeze to remove the extra dimension.  I don't think `dot` does that under the covers, but the result is the same.

This may also be called matrix vector multiplication, provided you don't insist on calling the 1d `x` a row vector or column vector.

---

Now for a 2d `x`, with shape (3,1):

```
In [175]: x2 = x[:,None]
In [176]: x2
Out[176]: 
array([[7],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [177]: x2.shape
Out[177]: (3, 1)
In [178]: np.dot(w,x2)
Out[178]: 
array([[20],
       [56]])
In [179]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',w,x2)
Out[179]: 
array([[20],
       [56]])
```

The sum is over `j`, the last axis of `w`, and 2nd to the last of `x`.  To do the same with elementwise we have to use broadcasting to generate a 3d `outer` product, and then do the sum to reduce the dimension back to 2.

```
In [180]: (w[:,:,None]*x2[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[180]: 
array([[20],
       [56]])
```

In this example a `(2,3) dot (3,1) => (2,1)`.  That's perfectly normal matrix product behavior.  In the first `(2,3) dot (3,) => (2,)`.  To me this is a logical generalization.  `(3,) dot (3,) => scalar` (as opposed to ()` is a bit more of a special case.

I suspect the first case is mainly a problem for people who see a (3,) shape and think (1,3), a row-vector.  `(2,3) dot (1,3)` doesn't work, because of the mismatch between the 3 and the 1.