# Numpy transposing a vector

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

How can I transpose vector with numpy?
I am trying

```
import numpy as np
center = np.array([1,2])
center_t = np.transpose(center)
```

But it doesn't work, how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array)

Comment: If you want a column vector start with a row vector.  Your `center` is a 1d array.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape should do the trick.

```
center = np.array([1,2])

print(center.reshape(-1,1))
```

> array([[1],
>          [2]])

However, for n-dimensional arrays, this will transpose the array.

```
print(center.T)
```

For example:

```
a = np.array([['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']])


print(a)

array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], dtype='<U1')

print(a.T)

array([['a', 'd', 'g'],
       ['b', 'e', 'h'],
       ['c', 'f', 'i']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Did you try this out?

Comment: You're using a different array. This doesn't work with the OP's input.

Answer (score 0):

To transpose an array, a matrix, data needs to have two dimensions. Here your data is 1D.

You can use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to obtain a two dimension vertical array/matrix from a 1D array/matrix. [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) is its horizontal equivalent.

```
import numpy as np
center = np.array([1,2])
center_t = np.vstack(center)
```

Comment: `vstack` does a lot of work to simply change a (2) shape into a (2,1) shape.  It makes 2 (1,1) arrays and concatenates them.

Comment: `np.atleast_2d(center).T` will do the same thing, but more directly.

Answer (score 0):

The transposition of a 1D array is itself, a 1D array. Unfortunately, it is working precisely how it is meant to.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-numpy-array).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,4])[np.newaxis]
print(a)
print(a.T)
```

`np.newaxis` essentially just increases the dimension of the array, so that you're transposing a 2D array, as you would be in Matlab.