# Python ValueError: diag requires an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to take a diagonal matrix but unfortunately, I am getting an error. My code is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ,2])
b = np.diagonal((a)*(a).T)
```

Comment: Did you test the array you pass to `diagonal`?  Or the terms in it, like `a.T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ,2]).reshape(1,-1)
b = np.diagonal((a)*(a).T)
```

The goal is to make this into a matrix of two dimensions rather than a one dimensional array as it was originally declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ,2])[np.newaxis]
b = np.diagonal((a)*(a).T)
```

Refer: [Transposing a 1D NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array)