# How to transpose print output in python

Tags: python, regex, transpose

i have build this little code to grab the pkeys(numbers) from the string (string could be of 1 page also) and then display the unique pkeys row wise. for example if the string is "Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 
is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755,5445454 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data"

output should be:
48021088
1029755
5445454

but right now my output is like [4802108 1029755 2
544545]

Note : it should not take 2 as pkey from the string "2M" i.e 2 month

Also, whenever i copy a long string in this code, i have to put \ after the end of each line to make it run, is there something i can do as soon as i copy a string from outlook or any other source and paste in this code, it should automatically format it and insert \ by iteself.

[image]

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


regex = ('\d+')
match = re.findall(regex, 'Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 \
is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data \
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments \
52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 52598110, \
35602558 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data \
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 \
is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data \
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is \
older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M, \
Error while loading Structured Product market data \
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 489459, 104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459, \
104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459, 104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459, \
104322960 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data')
res = list(map(int,match))
x = res
# print(str(x))
unique_numbers = list(set(x))
print(np.transpose(unique_numbers))
```

Comment: To allow your string to span multiple lines, put it in triple quotes: `'''...'''` or `"""..."""`.

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list, that is why you get `[4802108 1029755 2 544545]`

Answer (score 2):

Strings delimited by `' '` or `" "` are supposed to be on a single line. They can be made into multiple lines by either using `\` at the end of each line or delimiting them by `''' '''` or `""" """`.

Regarding your regex, I see that you use `\d+` to indicate at least one digit. You can change that to at least *n* digits by using `\d{n,}`.

Comment: Thanks alexander i tried \d{3,} and it worked, can you please help on the first part, how can i put a long script let say of 1000words in one line

Comment: As per jasonharper's comment and my answer, you can use triple quotes, so `''' '''` or `""" """`.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it worked thanks again, only the last part is left how can i transpose the print outpur from column wise to row wise

Comment: however i am using print(np.transpose(unique_numbers)) but seems its not working

Comment: Why do you need to transpose it ?

Comment: You should instead use `print(*unique_numbers)` this prints as desired. OP is simply trying to print a list space separated on the same line

Comment: i need the result in different rows

Comment: @ChrisOram : can we transpose this ?print(*unique_numbers)

Comment: If you only have a 1D array, it should not matter whether it is in a row or in a column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954747/13507154).

Comment: @Naina what do you mean transpose? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: actually when i paste the output in excel it gets pasted in a single row like 48021088 52598110 35602558 etc . however i need when i paste the output in excel it should be in different rows one after the other

Comment: can we please have a group chat ?

Comment: Sure, you can just do `for i in unique_numbers: print(i)`. That way each goes on a separate line and when you copy and paste into excel they are in one column

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
import re

regex = (r'(?<=\s)(\d+)(?=\s|,)') # positive and negative look assertions

# note use of triple quotes to negate use of \
match = re.findall(regex, """Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755
is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments
52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 52598110, 35602558 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 52598110,
35602558 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 48021088, 1029755
is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is
older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 612292, 52598110 is older than 2M,
Error while loading Structured Product market data
Failure: Cannot retrieve market data: [Historical correlation for instruments 489459, 104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459,
104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459, 104322960 is older than 2M, Historical correlation for instruments 489459,
104322960 is older than 2M, Error while loading Structured Product market data""")

unique_numbers = list(set(match))
print(*unique_numbers)  # print as required
```

---

**Explanation**

From the Python [Regex docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

`(?<=...)` Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for `...` that ends at the current position. This is called a positive lookbehind assertion.

`(?=...)` Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion.

Together these make up a look around assertion. We then have `<look behind>(\d+)<look ahead>`. The `()` indicates this is the matching group - what is returned from the `findall` call. Then `\d+` is as before - more than one digit.

Comment: for i in unique_numbers: print(i) this has solved the purpose

Comment: can you please demistify this line for me : regex = (r'(?<=(\s|,))(\d+)(?=(\s|,))')

Comment: res = [i[1] for i in match] this line as well

Comment: See the revised (and polished) version. I have edited with an explanation too :)