# Convert numpy array to numpy column python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and numpy.
I am trying to convert a 1D array into a column , I used transpose, but not working,
please any help, I attached the code:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3])
print(x)
y=x.T
print(y)
#output should be:
#y=[[1],
 #   [2],
#    [3]]
```

Comment: Did you try np.transpose ?

Comment: `Use y = x[:, None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transpose` for 2d array and you can see difference for your output you can use `.reshape(-1,1)` like below:

```
>>> x.reshape(-1,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Or You can read with more detail in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array) and try this:

```
>>> np.array([x]).T

>>> np.transpose([x])
```

Comment: and Dani Mesejo, 

Thank you for your answers, it works, and I accept your answer, thank you so much ,

Comment: I added another question for repeating, hope you could have a look, and help me, 

Thank you so much

Comment: @coder_beginner definitely I take look