# Creating arrays N x 1 in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In MATLAB, one would simply say

```
L = 2^8
x = (-L/2:L/2-1)';
```

Which creates an array of size L X 1.

How might I create this in Python?

I tried:

```
L = 2**8
x = np.arange(-L/2.0,L/ 2.0)
```

Which doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing a 1D NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array)

Comment: what's wrong with `x`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
x.reshape((-1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB code produces a (1,n) size matrix, which is transposed to (n,1)

```
>> 2:5
ans =

   2   3   4   5

>> (2:5)'
ans =

   2
   3
   4
   5
```

MATLAB matrices are always 2d (or higher).  `numpy` arrays can be 1d or even 0d.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

In `numpy`:

`arange` produces a 1d array:

```
In [165]: np.arange(2,5)
Out[165]: array([2, 3, 4])
In [166]: _.shape
Out[166]: (3,)
```

There are various ways of adding a trailing dimension to the array:

```
In [167]: np.arange(2,5)[:,None]
Out[167]: 
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]])
In [168]: np.arange(2,5).reshape(3,1)
Out[168]: 
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

`numpy` has a transpose, but its behavior with 1d arrays is not what people expect from a 2d array.  It's actually more powerful and general than MATLAB's `'`.