# Python array tranpose

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

This is what I have:

```
someArray = [10]
print(np.tranpose(someArray))
```

and I'm getting:
`[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

But I want it vertically. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954747/5785250

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to convert your array to a numpy array, as long as this has not been done yet.
Now you just have a 1D array. In Python, it is important to have a 2D array to perform some array/matrix operations.
You just have to use an additional bracket pair [...]. Then you can simply use ".T" to transpose your array.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np

someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
someArray = np.array([someArray])
someArray_transposed = someArray.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

someArray = [0]*10
print(np.transpose(someArray).reshape((len(someArray),1)))
```