# How to convert a list to an array as there is a need to take transpose in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a `u0` list in which values are appended, and then I have to take the transpose of u0, but when I am doing this, I still get a row matrix, but I want to show it as a column matrix. From other answers, I learned that there would be no difference in calculations, but I want it to be shown as column matrix and this can be used further for calculations.
`x_mirror` is also a list.

```
u0 = []
for p in range(0,tpts):                              #initial condition at t = 0
    ts =  ((np.exp(alpha*((x_mirror[p]-x_start)**2))*(np.cos(k0*(x_mirror[p]-x_start)))))
    u0.append(ts)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "show as column matrix"? Do you mean in terms of, say, `np.shape` or in terms of formatting?

Comment: I mean in shape primarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an already existing stackoverflow post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array)) you can do the following to

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [2,4,6,8,10]

array1 = np.array(list1)[np.newaxis]
print(array1)
print(array1.transpose())
```

For the above code you can see the output here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to display vertically, you can create your class as a subclass of `list`.

```
class ColumnList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        parts = '\n '.join(map(str, self))
        r = f'[{parts}]'
        return r

u0 = ColumnList()
for p in range(0,tpts):                              #initial condition at t = 0
    ts =  ((np.exp(alpha*((x_mirror[p]-x_start)**2))*(np.cos(k0*(x_mirror[p]-x_start)))))
    u0.append(ts)

# displays vertically:
u0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Suppose if we want the transposed matrix to be used for further calculations especially matrix multiplication, how can we do that? will there be much difference in the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape` -

```
u0 = [1, 2, 3]
np_u0_row = np.array(u0)
np_u0_col = np_u0_row.reshape((1, len(u0)))
print(np_u0_col.shape)
# (1, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I got the question right, but try to convert it into a 2-dimensional Array with the right number of rows and only one column.

```
rowMatrix = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
columnMatrix = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: but how to do this for this case? I am actually appending values in the list how do we do that in array?

Comment: What is your solution?