# Difference between a (20,) vector and (20, 1) Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I was taking the Machine Learning course by Andrew Ng and in one of the practice labs, they perform this operation for Linear Regression.

```
x = np.arange(0, 20, 1)
y = 1 + x**2
X = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

I checked out the shape of the arrays after the op

```
>>> print(x.shape,X.shape)
(20,) (20, 1)
```

What is the difference between x and X, and why can't we simply just use x.T instead of changing it to X ?

Comment: Because the transpose of 1d array is precisely another 1d array:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing a 1D NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array)

Comment: What's the difference? The shape is different!  I don't mean that as a joke.  That literally is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

gives you array like this 2d dimensions, this because each perceptron takes array of number not single number so you need to pass [1] not 1

```
[
[1]
[2]
]
```

x=np.arange(0, 20, 1)

```
[1
,
2
,
3
]
```

this can't be passed to ANN  you need to reshape it to be (rows and column) as this is only 1 dimension