# Python/transposed vector/multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, vector, transpose

I want to define the following matrix
A = b * c ^T.

So the product from a column vector b and a transposed column vector c. This product is a matrix.

In this case b and c have the same amount of components thus multiplication is possible.

The np.transpose(c) command did not really help me because when I did

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([1,1])
c = np.array([0,1])

d = np.transpose(c)
A = b * d
print(A)
```

I received the vector [0,1] but I should be receiving a matrix. Because a column vector multiplied with a transposed column vector yields a matrix.
What could I do instead?

Comment: perhaps this could use a concrete example.

Comment: Please share more code. Show how you created / defined `c` and `b`.

Comment: numpy docs say that a transposed vector is unchanged. You may be assuming it is an Nx1 array, but that's not what it says on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Comment: Okay I just added some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing a 1D NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are facing is when you define the matrix `b` and `c`. When you work with matrix in python, normally, the definition is the following:

A list of list of line vectors of the matrix.

```
A = [[a11,a12,a13,...],
     [a21,a22,a23, ...],
     ...]
```

So be careful, because you are defining the matrix in some vector way. As I can see you consider `b` and `c` column matrix the way I will define it is this:

```py
b = np.array([[1],[1]])
c = np.array([[0],[1]])
```