# Correct syntax for matrix multiplication in Numpy?

Tags: python, math, matrix, vector

I want to convert the following equation into a Python code using Numpy. Note that mu is a 3x1 vector sigma is a 3x3 matrix using a covariance matrix.

[image]

```
u = np.array([0.0493, 0.0770, 0.0886])
cov_matrix = ([[0.0017, -0.0017, -0.0021],
               [-0.0017, 0.0396, 0.0309],
               [-0.0021, 0.0309, 0.0392]])

def hyperbola(u):
    k = u * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix)                       
    l = u * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) * u[:, np.newaxis]    
    m = np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix)                           

    g = (l * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) - k * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) * u[:, np.newaxis]) / (l*m - k**2)
    h = (m * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) * u[:, np.newaxis] - k * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix)) / (l*m - k**2)
    
    a = h * cov_matrix * h[:, np.newaxis]
    b = 2 * g * cov_matrix * h[:, np.newaxis]
    c = g * cov_matrix * g[:, np.newaxis]

    return np.sqrt(a * u**2 + b*u + c)


efficient_frontier = hyperbola(u)
```

I constructed the above, however, the resulting hyperbola is a 3x3x3. What exactly am I doing wrong? I did have some issues transposing the mu vector, perhaps it's related to that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have now created the below code, which seems to produce the correct structure of code but not the expected shape of the curve.

```
def hyperbola(u):
    k = u @ np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ np.ones_like(u)                  
    l = u @ np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ u
    m = np.ones_like(u) @ np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ np.ones_like(u)

    g = (l * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ np.ones_like(u) - k * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ u) / (l*m - k**2)
    h = (m * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ u - k * np.linalg.inv(cov_matrix) @ np.ones_like(u)) / (l*m - k**2)
    
    a = h @ cov_matrix @ h
    b = 2 * g @ cov_matrix @ h
    c = g @ cov_matrix @ g

    return np.sqrt(a * u**2 + b*u + c)

efficient_frontier = hyperbola(u)

plt.plot(u, efficient_frontier)
plt.xlabel('Volatility')
plt.ylabel('Mean Return')
plt.grid(True)
```

The expected curve should look like the red curve below. Why am I getting a different result? I have gone through all the variables multiple times and can't find a discrepancy.

[image]

Comment: The multiply `*` symbol is for element-wise multiplication not matrix multiplication. For numpy, you want to use `@`. You can also use `h.T` for transposes of matrices/vectors.

Comment: That's simple enough. Makes sense, thank you. As for the transpose using .T, I have noticed that this does not work properly for vectors as they just maintain the same form. The `h[:, np.newaxis]` method has been the only one I have found so far to do this.

Comment: See [Transposing a 1d numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954603/transposing-a-1d-numpy-array). You probably NEVER need to transpose your vectors AT ALL if they are stored as 1-dimensional numpy array. Don't use `.T` nor `[:, np.newaxis]`. You would only need to transpose your vectors explicitly if they were stored as numpy 2d array. Your vectors are stored as 1-dimensional arrays of shape `3`, not as 2-dimensional arrays of shape `(3, 1)` or `(1, 3)`, so you do NOT need to transpose them explicitly. Just use `@` for multiplication and numpy will know how to handle the vectors.

Comment: By the way, on stackoverflow if you include code in your question, then it is considered good style to make it "reproducible", or in other words, self-contained. Here no one can run your code, because it calls `hyperbola(u)` without defining variable `u`. So it would be good style to add an explicit `u = np.array([1, 2, 3])` or something similar in the code that you show us.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Please update your post to make it clear whether you're looking for some kind of magical OCR solution, or whether you just want to manually translate the math from your image into numpy expresions. Because sure, you almost certainly don't want that first option, but [writing a good question](/help/how-to-ask) does require some effort, not just dumping an image into a post =)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have amended the title accordingly. I can now see my question was about the correct syntax for matrix multiplications in Numpy.