# Sum ndarray values

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easier way to get the sum of all values (assuming they are all numbers) in an ndarray :

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

result = 0
(dim0,dim1) = m.shape
for i in range(dim0):
    for j in range(dim1):
        result += m[i,j]

print result
```

The above code seems somewhat verbose for a straightforward mathematical operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`numpy.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
result = np.sum(matrix)
```

or equivalently, the `.sum()` method of the array:

```
result = matrix.sum()
```

By default this sums over all elements in the array - if you want to sum over a particular axis, you should pass the `axis` argument as well, e.g. `matrix.sum(0)` to sum over the first axis.

As a side note your "`matrix`" is actually a `numpy.ndarray`, not a `numpy.matrix` - [they are different classes that behave slightly differently](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935), so it's best to avoid confusing the two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the `sum` method:

```
result = m.sum()
```

---

For example,

```
In [17]: m = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [18]: m.sum()
Out[18]: 10
```

---

By the way, NumPy has a matrix class which is [different than "regular" numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/190597). So calling a regular ndarray `matrix` causes some cognitive dissonance. To help others understand your code, you may want to change the name `matrix` to something else.