# Dealing with dimension collapse in python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

A recurring error I run into when using NumPy is that an attempt to index an array fails because one of the dimensions of the array was a singleton, and thus that dimension got wiped out and can't be indexed.  This is especially problematic in functions designed to operate on arrays of arbitrary size.  I'm looking for the cheapest, most universal way to avoid this error.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
f = (lambda t, u, i=0: t[:,i]*u[::-1])
a = np.eye(3)
b = np.array([1,2,3])
f(a,b)
f(a[:,0],b[1])
```

The first call works as expected.  The second call fails in two ways: 1) `t` can't be indexed by `[:,0]` because is has shape `(3,)`, and 2) `u` can't be indexed at all because it's a scalar.

Here are the fixes that occur to me:

1) Use `np.atleast_1d` and `np.atleast_2d` etc. (possibly with conditionals to make sure that the dimensions are in the right order) inside `f` to make sure that all parameters have the dimensions they need.  This precludes use of lambdas, and can take a few lines that I would rather not need.

2) Instead of writing `f(a[:,0],b[1])` above, use `f(a[:,[0]],b[[1]])`.  This is fine, but I always have to remember to put in the extra brackets, and if the index is stored in a variable you might not know if you should put the extra brackets in or not.  E.g.:

```
idx = 1
f(a[:,[0]],b[[idx]])
idx = [2,0,1]
f(a[:,[0]],b[idx])
```

In this case, you would seem to have to call `np.atleast_1d` on `idx` first, which may be even more cumbersome than putting `np.atleast_1d` in the function.

3) In some cases I can get away with just not putting in an index.  E.g.:

```
f = lambda t, u: t[0]*u
f(a,b)
f(a[:,0],b[0])
```

This works, and is apparently the slickest solution when it applies.  But it doesn't help in every case (in particular, your dimensions have to be in the right order to begin with).

So, are there better approaches than the above?

Comment: Many of the numpy functions have many lines of python code that reshape and massage the inputs, before performing the central action.  Look for example at what `atleast_1d` does (it is 10 lines long).

Comment: I feel your pain. Here's how I usually deal with this: First I store the input shape and check if the input is scalar, then I apply something like `np.atleast_1d` and do my computation, in the end I reshape the result to match the input shape (E.g. transform back to scalar). Downside: It's a lot of boilerplate. Upside: More flexible interface, and less surprises for the caller. I think it's worth it for a fairly general function that is part of your domain specific library.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to avoid this behaviour.

First, whenever you index into a dimension of an `np.ndarray` with a `slice` rather than an integer, the number of dimensions of the output will be the same as that of the input:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
print x[:, 0].shape               # integer indexing
# (3,)

print x[:, 0:1].shape             # slice
# (3, 1)
```

This is my preferred way of avoiding the problem, since it generalizes very easily from single-element to multi-element selections (e.g. `x[:, i:i+1]` vs `x[:, i:i+n]`).

As you've already touched on, you can also avoid dimension loss by using any sequence of integers to index into a dimension:

```
print x[:, [0]].shape             # list
# (3, 1)

print x[:, (0,)].shape            # tuple
# (3, 1)

print x[:, np.array((0,))].shape  # array
# (3, 1)
```

If you choose to stick with integer indices, you can always insert a new singleton dimension using `np.newaxis` (or equivalently, `None`):

```
print x[:, 0][:, np.newaxis]
# (3, 1)

print x[:, 0][:, None]
# (3, 1)
```

Or else you could manually reshape it to the correct size (here using `-1` to infer the size of the first dimension automatically):

```
print x[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1).shape
# (3, 1)
```

Finally, you can use an `np.matrix` rather than an `np.ndarray`. `np.matrix` behaves more like a MATLAB matrix, where singleton dimensions are left in whenever you index with an integer:

```
y = np.matrix(x)
print y[:, 0].shape
# (3, 1)
```

However, you should be aware that there are a [number of other important differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151251/1461210) between `np.matrix` and `np.ndarray`, for example the `*` operator performs elementwise multiplication on arrays, but matrix multiplication on matrices. In most circumstances it's best to stick to `np.ndarrays`.