# How do I transform a "SciPy sparse matrix" to a "NumPy matrix"?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, networkx

I am using a python function called "incidence_matrix(G)", which returns the incident matrix of graph. It is from Networkx package. The problem that I am facing is the return type of this function is "Scipy Sparse Matrix". I need to have the Incident matrix in the format of numpy matrix or array. I was wondering if there is any easy way of doing that or not? Or is there any built-in function that can do this transformation for me or not?

Thanks

Comment: Actually yes, it works and gives you an array. I was looking for a way to directly (using python functions) get the matrix having all zeros and ones. 
But thank you for that, I think finally I will go with the array if I could not find anything better.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u).

Comment: Yes, I used that but the problem with that is when you use it, it only stores the whole sparse matrix as one element in a matrix. when you wanna print it, you will see this:
[[ <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]]

Comment: What about `numpy.matrix(numpy.array(<your_matrix_object>))`?

Comment: I have already tried that. Same results.

Comment: OK. I think this is what you want `numpy.matrix(<your_matrix_object>.toarray())`.

Comment: `np.array()` or `np.matrix()` don't know anything special about sparse matrices.  That's why they just wrap the input without any transformation.  You need to use the sparse matrix methods.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The [`scipy.sparse.*_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) has several useful methods, for example, if `a` is e.g. `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`:

- `a.toarray()` -  Return a dense ndarray representation of this matrix. (`numpy.array`, recommended)
- `a.todense()` - Return a dense matrix representation of this matrix. (`numpy.matrix`)

Previously, these methods had shorthands (`.A` for `.toarray()`, and `.M` for `.todense()`), but these have been or will be deprecated as of Scipy v1.14.0.

Comment: Those two attributes have short aliases: if your sparse matrix is `a`, then `a.M` returns a dense numpy matrix object, and `a.A` returns a dense numpy array object. Unless you have very good reasons for it (and you probably don't!), stick to numpy arrays, i.e. `a.A`, and stay away from numpy matrix.

Answer (score 4):

I found that in the case of csr matrices, `todense()` and `toarray()` simply wrapped the tuples rather than producing a ndarray formatted version of the data in matrix form. This was unusable for the skmultilearn classifiers I'm training.

I translated it to a [lil matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix)- a format numpy can parse accurately, and then ran `toarray()` on that:

```
sparse.lil_matrix(<my-sparse_matrix>).toarray()
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to call the todense() method on the data:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph([(1,2)])

In [3]: nx.incidence_matrix(G)
Out[3]: 
<2x1 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [4]: nx.incidence_matrix(G).todense()
Out[4]: 
matrix([[ 1.],
        [ 1.]])

In [5]: nx.incidence_matrix(G).todense().A
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```