# How to convert a scipy row matrix into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((2,2))
b = A.sum(axis=0)
```

The matrix `b` now has the form

```
matrix([[ 0.,  0.]])
```

However, I'd like it to become an array like this:

```
array([ 0.,  0.])
```

This can by done by `b = np.asarray(b)[0]`, but that does not seem very elegant, especially compared to MATLAB's `b(:)`. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576524/how-do-i-transform-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-to-a-numpy-matrix; in particular, note that the sparse matrix has the method `.toarray()`, the result of which you could reshape into a one-dimensional numpy array.

Comment: MATLAB's `b(:)` - what's the size?  Still 2d isnt' it?  `(:)` is a bit like a `np.ravel`, except MATLAB is always 2d or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.A1` will do the job.

```
In [83]: A
Out[83]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [84]: A.A
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])

In [85]: b=A.sum(axis=0)

In [86]: b
Out[86]: matrix([[ 0.,  0.]])

In [87]: b.A1
Out[87]: array([ 0.,  0.])

In [88]: A.A.sum(axis=0)     # another way
Out[88]: array([ 0.,  0.])
```

You can up vote this, or add to my top grossing answer here: [Numpy matrix to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/20765358#20765358)  :)

`A` is a sparse matrix.  Sparse sum is performed with a matrix product (an appropriate matrix of 1s).  The result is a dense matrix.

Sparse matrix has a `toarray()` method, with a `.A` shortcut.

Dense matrix also has those, but it also has a `.A1` (poorly documented - hence all my hits), which flattens as well.

The doc for `A1`:

```
Return `self` as a flattened `ndarray`.
Equivalent to ``np.asarray(x).ravel()``
```

In fact the code is

```
return self.__array__().ravel()
```

====================

Is MATLAB `b(:)` really the equivalent?

> A(:)
>   is all the elements of A, regarded as a single column.

If I read that correctly, the `numpy` equivalent is a transpose, or `b.ravel().T`.  The shape would be (2,1).  But in MATLAB a column matrix is the simplest form of matrix.

```
In [94]: b.T
Out[94]: 
matrix([[ 0.],
        [ 0.]])
```

(I'm an old MATLAB programmer, with Octave on my standby computer.  And a copy of 3.5 on some old Windows disk. :) ).

Comment: Indeed, accoding to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html, .A1 is equivalent to `np.asarray(x).ravel()`, and seems like the most concise option.

Answer (score 1):

There are different options here. For example, you could start by converting matrix `b` to a 2D array. Then you'll need to transform it into a 1D array. This can be easily accomplished through NumPy's [`squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) or [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
In [208]: np.asarray(b).squeeze()
Out[208]: array([ 0.,  0.])

In [209]: np.asarray(b).reshape((b.size,))
Out[209]: array([ 0.,  0.])
```

Alternatively, you could convert `A` to an array as suggested in @Warren Weckesser's comment. This would make it unnecessary to further convert `b`:

```
In [210]: A.toarray().sum(axis=0)
Out[210]: array([ 0.,  0.])
```