# Computing Euclidean distance for numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python so this question might look trivia. However, I did not find a similar case to mine. I have a matrix of coordinates for 20 nodes. I want to compute the euclidean distance between all pairs of nodes from this set and store them in a pairwise matrix. For example, If I have 20 nodes, I want the end result to be a matrix of (20,20) with values of euclidean distance between each pairs of nodes. I tried to used a for loop to go through each element of the coordinate set and compute euclidean distance as follows:

```
ncoord=numpy.matrix('3225   318;2387    989;1228    2335;57      1569;2288  8138;3514   2350;7936   314;9888    4683;6901   1834;7515   8231;709   3701;1321    8881;2290   2350;5687   5034;760    9868;2378   7521;9025   5385;4819   5943;2917   9418;3928   9770')
n=20 
c=numpy.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        c[i][j]=math.sqrt((ncoord[i][0]-ncoord[j][0])**2+(ncoord[i][1]-ncoord[j][1])**2)
```

How ever, I am getting an error of "input must be a square array
". I wonder if anybody knows what is happening here. 
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the definition of `ncoord`. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: What is your n? `for j in range(i+1,n-1)` will do `j=i+1, i+2, ..., n-2`. My guess is you want both those ranges to go up to `n`, not `n-1`.

Comment: @MarkG yes I have 20 nodes (n=20) and I want both indices go up to n. I tried n instead of n-1 but I got the same error. I can easily code this in MATLAB but I have to use Python. Indexing in Python is different so I might be wrong.

Comment: Then both your for loops should go up to n: `for i in range(0,n):`, and `for j in range(i+1,n):` If this isn't your bug you then will need to show more code.

Comment: @MarkG yes this is not my bug. my code is what I mentioned in the main question. I have nothing more

Comment: Why have you chosen to use a matrix rather than an array? Have you considered parsing the input data into the form np.array([ [x0,y0],[x1,y1] ... [xn,yn] ],dtype=([('x','<f8'),('y','<f8')])  see this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy?rq=1

Answer (score 29):

There are much, much faster alternatives to using nested `for` loops for this. I'll show you two different approaches - the first will be a more general method that will introduce you to broadcasting and vectorization, and the second uses a more convenient scipy library function.

---

1. The general way, using broadcasting & vectorization

---

One of the first things I'd suggest doing is switching to using `np.array` rather than `np.matrix`. Arrays are preferred for [a number of reasons](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935), most importantly because they can have >2 dimensions, and they make element-wise multiplication much less awkward.

```
import numpy as np

ncoord = np.array(ncoord)
```

With an array, we can eliminate the nested `for` loops by inserting a new singleton dimension and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the subtraction over it:

```
# indexing with None (or np.newaxis) inserts a new dimension of size 1
print(ncoord[:, :, None].shape)
# (20, 2, 1)

# by making the 'inner' dimensions equal to 1, i.e. (20, 2, 1) - (1, 2, 20),
# the subtraction is 'broadcast' over every pair of rows in ncoord
xydiff = ncoord[:, :, None] - ncoord[:, :, None].T

print(xydiff.shape)
# (20, 2, 20)
```

This is equivalent to looping over every pair of rows using nested for loops, but much, much faster!

```
xydiff2 = np.zeros((20, 2, 20), dtype=xydiff.dtype)
for ii in range(20):
    for jj in range(20):
        for kk in range(2):
            xydiff[ii, kk, jj] = ncoords[ii, kk] - ncoords[jj, kk]

# check that these give the same result
print(np.all(xydiff == xydiff2))
# True
```

The rest we can also do using vectorized operations:

```
# we square the differences and sum over the 'middle' axis, equivalent to
# computing (x_i - x_j) ** 2 + (y_i - y_j) ** 2
ssdiff = (xydiff * xydiff).sum(1)

# finally we take the square root
D = np.sqrt(ssdiff)
```

The whole thing could be done in one line like this:

```
D = np.sqrt(((ncoord[:, :, None] - ncoord[:, :, None].T) ** 2).sum(1))
```

---

2. The lazy way, using `pdist`

---

It turns out that there's already a fast and convenient function for computing all pairwise distances: [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

d = pdist(ncoord)

# pdist just returns the upper triangle of the pairwise distance matrix. to get
# the whole (20, 20) array we can use squareform:

print(d.shape)
# (190,)

D2 = squareform(d)
print(D2.shape)
# (20, 20)

# check that the two methods are equivalent
print np.all(D == D2)
# True
```

Comment: This broadcasting is magical to me. How can I get some intuition about it?

Comment: Thanks for the amazing method but it is still much slower than cross product whereas the complexity looks the same.

Comment: I also had some memory issues when computing on a large matrix (1000 * 20000) with the method 1 which i did not have with the method 2 (scipy).

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        c[i, j] = math.sqrt((ncoord[i, 0] - ncoord[j, 0])**2 
        + (ncoord[i, 1] - ncoord[j, 1])**2)
```

**Note**: `ncoord[i, j]` is not the same as `ncoord[i][j]` for a Numpy *matrix*. This appears to be the source of confusion. If `ncoord` is a Numpy *array* then they will give the same result.

For a Numpy *matrix*, `ncoord[i]` returns the *ith row* of `ncoord`, which itself is a Numpy *matrix* object with shape 1 x 2 in your case. Therefore, `ncoord[i][j]` actually means: take the *ith row* of `ncoord` *and* take the *jth row* of that 1 x 2 *matrix*. This is where your indexing problems comes about when `j` > 0.

Regarding your comments on assigning to `c[i][j]` "working", it shouldn't. At least on my build of Numpy 1.9.1 it shouldn't work if your indices `i` and `j` iterates up to `n`.

As an aside, remember to add the transpose of the matrix `c` to itself.

It is recommended to use Numpy arrays instead of matrix. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u).

If your coordinates are stored as a Numpy array, then pairwise distance can be computed as:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

pairwise_distances = pdist(ncoord, metric="euclidean", p=2)
```

or simply

```
pairwise_distances = pdist(ncoord)
```

since the default metric is "euclidean", and default "p" is 2.

In a comment below I mistakenly mentioned that the result of pdist is a n x n matrix.
To get a n x n matrix, you will need to do the following:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

pairwise_distances = squareform(pdist(ncoord))
```

or

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

pairwise_distances = cdist(ncoord, ncoord)
```

Comment: I actually did that but did not put it here. The last line of my code is:         c[j][i]=c[i][j]

Comment: Thank you it is working now. However I am misunderstood now. I thought when we want to call an element of a matrix in Python, we need to call it as a[][], but you are using a[,]. Why did you use the second format to read data from ncoord but saved the distance in c matrix by calling c elements like c[][]?

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete information. I will try the other method you mentioned to see if I can get the same matrix size as the result ( I assume that pairwise_distances is a n*n matrix)

Comment: Yes `pairwise_distances` will be a n x n matrix if n is the number of points you have.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand the difference between ncoord[i,j] and ncoord[i][j]

Comment: @Fairy I've fixed the typo regarding assignment to an element of `c`. They should all use the same format `c[i, j]` rather than `c[i][j]`.

Comment: c[i][j] is working ok. What is the difference between them?(c[i][j] and c[i,j])

Comment: @Fairy When you chain your indexing like that, what you are really doing is first grabbing the ith row of `c`, then indexing the jth element in the first dimension of that row. With an `np.array`, `c[i].shape == (n,)` (i.e. it has only one dimension that's `n` long) so indexing the jth element is no problem. However, `np.matrix` behaves differently in that `c[i].shape == (1, n)`. Since the singleton row dimension is kept, when you then try to index the jth element in the first dimension of `c[i]`, your index goes out of bounds. The take-home message is to use `np.array`, not `np.matrix`!

Answer (score 1):

What I figure you wanted to do: You said you wanted a 20 by 20 matrix... but the one you coded is triangular.

Thus I coded a complete 20x20 matrix instead.

```
distances = []
for i in range(len(ncoord)):
    given_i = []
    for j in range(len(ncoord)):
        d_val = math.sqrt((ncoord[i, 0]-ncoord[j,0])**2+(ncoord[i,1]-ncoord[j,1])**2)
        given_i.append(d_val)

    distances.append(given_i)

    # distances[i][j] = distance from i to j
```

SciPy way:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
# Isn't scipy nice - can also use pdist... works in the same way but different recall method.
distances = cdist(ncoord, ncoord, 'euclidean')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try your method as well.

Comment: Anytime you have to do a double loop through an array in numpy, you're losing the speed advantage afforded by NumPy in the firstplace.  You want to broadcast whenever possible.  However, for some operations, I think including this one, you can't broadcast because the values at each step depend on their neighbors.  In these cases, SciPy solutions are usually optimized at the c-level (see cython), so they can still be much faster.  I'd expect the cdist function to be much faster than the double loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own custom sqrt sum sqaures is not always safe, they can overflow or underflow. Speed wise they are same

```py
np.hypot(
    np.subtract.outer(x, x),
    np.subtract.outer(y, y)
)
```

### Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# 0.0
```

### Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# inf
```

### No Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e-200
```

### No Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e+200
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233365/7035448)