# Formal name for this matrix operation (multiplying matrix columns by column vector)?

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication, nomenclature

I've written the following Python/Pandas code to multiply each column of an M row x N col dataframe (A) by an M x 1 dataframe (b) to yield the M x N dataframe C:

```
def multiply_columns(A, b):
    C = pd.DataFrame(A.values * b.values, columns=A.columns, index=b.index)
    return C
```

In other words, it multiplies each column of a matrix by a column vector of equal length.

The code works fine, but I can't recall the formal name for this operation. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

It is called "broadcasting".  Please see the `numpy` documentation on the subject: [Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Also, it is important to note that `A.values` and `b.values` are not matrices, they are arrays.  This may seem like a minor detail, but it is very important.  Many mathematical operations on matrices produce completely different results than their corresponding operations on arrays.  So, for example, `M1*M2` is a matrix product for matrices, while it is an element-by-element multiplication for arrays.  See more details in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151251/3604159).