# Numpy Select indices with complex conditions

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix, indices

Simple question... I hope...

I've got a matrix, **a** , of size (n x m)

```
a = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[6,4,1]])
```

and I'd like to extract a bool matrix, **b**, of size (n x m) for the following condition;

```
b = 3 < a > 7 and a != 6
```

However it is throwing the following error.

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()

Any help with this because I'm quite stuck.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use matrices? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/1461850)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `and` with arrays as you're trying to compare a single value with an array you have to use `&`, also you need to enclose the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence:

```
In [56]:

a[(a > 3 ) & (a < 7) & (a != 6)]
Out[56]:
matrix([[4]])
```