# Python: Array subtract Matrix - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have code below that help me to use array minus matrix but the system return error at this line `union = total - zero`. `zero` is actually the count of intersection. If I put a comment # in front of `union=total-zero` I can manually get my answer in python window by typing `total - zero`. `total` and `zero` are array in this case.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from numpy import matrix,ones
from itertools import product,chain,combinations,permutations,izip
from collections import Counter

####################################################################

def diffs(a,b):
    # collect sliding window differences
    # length of window determined by the shorter array
    # if a,b are not arrays, need to replace b[...]-a with
    # a list comprehension
    n,m=len(a),len(b)
    if n>m:
        # ensure s is the shorter
        b,a=a,b # switch
        n,m=len(a),len(b)
        # may need to correct for sign switch
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,1+m-n):
        result.append(b[i:i+n]-a)
    return result

###################################################################

def alldiffs(a,b):
    # collect all the differences for elements of a and b
    # a,b could be lists or arrays of arrays, or 2d arrays
    result=[]
    for aa in a:
        for bb in b:
            result.append(diffs(aa,bb))
    return result

###################################################################

def count_total(a,b):
    #count the total number of element for two arrays in different list
    #return [sum(map(len, i)) for i in product(a, b)]
    y= lambda x:len(x)
    result=[]
    for a1 in a:
        for b1 in b:
            result.append(y(a1) + y(b1))
    return result

##################################################################

def count_zero(obj):
    #count the total number of zero for two arrays in different list
    if isinstance(obj,list):
        return list(map(count_zero,obj))
    else:
        return Counter(obj)[0]

# define the 3 arrays
# each is a list of 1d arrays

a=[np.array([2,2,1,2]),np.array([1,3])]
b=[np.array([4,2,1])]
c=[np.array([1,2]),np.array([4,3])]

comb_set = list(itertools.combinations([a,b,c],2))
for i, j in itertools.combinations([a,b,c],2):
    all_diffs = alldiffs(i,j)
    total = count_total(i,j)
    zero = count_zero(all_diffs)
    total = np.array(total)
    total = total[: np.newaxis]  
    zero = np.array(zero)
    union = total-zero
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe that your last `total`
 attribution, in the slice, has a excellent comma. Check it

Comment: And, where come from this `alldiffs`?

Comment: alldiffs is a defined function. Do you mean 'union=total,-zero'? It returns error.

Comment: Post `alldiffs` method.

Comment: I just updated the code this is the full coding. The purpose of this code is to compare arrays of different sizes. There's shifting window just in case that the array size is different.

Comment: You are trying to make an operation between 2 different types, array and matrices. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151251/841339) to understand better this case

Comment: I've changed my matrix to array. Still it can't solve my issue when I try to loop them. If i type in window manually total - zero. Yes it did return my answer but when there are more than one set of arrays involved it still give me the error.

Comment: Did you understand that matrices are 2D only?

Answer (score 1):

> I can manually get my answer in python window by typing total - zero.

This works, because at that point, you use the *last* `total` and `zero`.

If you print out `i` and `j` inside the loop (or examine `comb_set` carefully), you'll find that `j` varies from a list with 1 element (an `np.ndarray`) to a 2-element list and back again to a 1-element list in the last iteration. The 1 element lists don't cause the error, but the 2-element list does.

This is obviously a result from your differently sized input lists `a`, `b` and `c`. You may need to think how to handle `a`, `b` and `c` (and their combinations) differently.

Comment: It is solved using this method. cc=map(sub,total,zero). Thanks.