# What is the difference between using matrix multiplication with np.matrix arrays, and dot()/tensor() with np.arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

At the moment, my code is written entirely using numpy arrays, `np.array`.

Define `m` as a np.array of 100 values, `m.shape = (100,)`. There is also a multi-dimensional array, `C.shape = (100,100)`.

The operation I would like to compute is

```
m^T * C * m
```

where `m^T` should be of shape `(1,100)`, `m` of shape `(100,1)`, and `C` of shape `(100,100)`.

I'm conflicted how to proceed. If I insist the data types must remain `np.arrays`, then I should probably you `numpy.dot()` or `numpy.tensordot()` and specify the axis. That would be something like

```
import numpy as np
result = np.dot(C, m)
final = np.dot(m.T, result)
```

though `m.T` is an array of the same shape as `m`. Also, that's doing two individual operations instead of one.

Otherwise, I should convert everything into `np.matrix` and proceed to use matrix multiplication there. The problem with this is I must convert all my `np.arrays` into `np.matrix`, do the operations, and then convert back to `np.array`.

What is the most efficient and intelligent thing to do?

EDIT:

Based on the answers so far, I think `np.dot(m^T, np.dot(C, m))` is probably the best way forward.

Comment: I would stick to arrays and use the (somewhat inconvenient) dot function for now, converting back and forth to matrix is annoying. It is likely that `np.matrix` will be deprecated or strongly discouraged several years from now, since Python 3.5 will now have a [dedicated matrix multiplication operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Comment: Given my dimensions, is it wiser to use `np.dot()` or `np.tensordot()`? I'm unsure whether one would need to specify the axis in this case.

Comment: `tensordot` just reshapes the arrays and does `dot`.  Matrix `*` probably does `dot` as well.  All will do your calculation in 2 steps.  `einsum` is another option, but with these small arrays I don't think it helps.  Do some of your own timing tests to measure 'efficiency`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage of working with matrices is that the `*`symbol performs a matrix multiplication, whereas it performs an element-wise multiplications with arrays. With arrays you need to use `dot`. See:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)
[What are the differences between numpy arrays and matrices? Which one should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u)

If `m` is a one dimensional array, *you don't need to transpose anything*, because for 1D arrays, transpose doesn't change anything:

```
In [28]: m.T.shape, m.shape
Out[28]: ((3,), (3,))
In [29]: m.dot(C)
Out[29]: array([15, 18, 21])

In [30]: C.dot(m)
Out[30]: array([ 5, 14, 23])
```

This is different if you add another dimension to `m`:

```
In [31]: mm = m[:, np.newaxis]

In [32]: mm.dot(C)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-28253c9b8898> in <module>()
----> 1 mm.dot(C)

ValueError: objects are not aligned

In [33]: (mm.T).dot(C)
Out[33]: array([[15, 18, 21]])

In [34]: C.dot(mm)
Out[34]: 
array([[ 5],
       [14],
       [23]])
```