# Arrays generation from different arrays and arrays/numpy modules?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to build an array which will contain arrays of increasing sizes based on the current values of array.

for example with

```
 current_array [100,33]
```

and

```
 limit = (n//10)
```

with n=current_array (thus limit_array=[10,3]

I want my output_array to be:
     [[1,...,10],[1,2,3]]

I wanted to avoid for loops; so I wanted to use arange like that:

```
 output_array=np.arange(current_array, limit_array, 2,dtype=I)
```

I understand this is not possible to do that since first two arguments for arange are floats only, but then how would you do that?

subsidiary questions:

1) I am not sure numpy can handle arrays of different sizes. If it is not, I can do this with a array array of arrays (https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). But I have to do an array multiplication of this array of array.
So will this be slower than array.arrays processed together? 
Or should I definitely find another solution?

2) As I said, I have a third np.array [1,2,3] I have to multiply the previous one with.
Will I obtain something like
[[[1,...,10]*1,[1,2,3]],[[1,...,10]*2,[2,4,6]],[[1,...,10]*3,[3,6,9]]] ?

Edit:
I also came up with

```
 result_array=np.array()
 result_array=np.append( np.arange(current_array, currentlimit, 1) for  currentlimit in limit_array)
```

but not sure it can work

Comment: Why not a list of arrays?  And stay away from `np.append`.

Comment: I want to use an array of array to be able to perform on it array operations on the nested array, which would be impossible with a list of array. Besides, why is np.append taboo?

Comment: But only a subset of array operations work on nested arrays, and ones that do work might not be any faster than list comprehensions.  `np.append` is just a frontend for `np.concatenate` and is often misused by new users.

Comment: This is something to test, indeed, but I would like to stay with uniform collection type. Thanks for the pointer to np.concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can avoid `for` loops as such, but you can use list comprehension and `np.arange()` , which should be a bit faster than normal `for` loops. Example -

```
np.array([np.arange(1, x+1) for x in limit_array])
```

Demo -

```
In [34]: import numpy as np

In [35]: ca = np.array([100,33])

In [39]: na = ca // 10

In [40]: na
Out[40]: array([10,  3], dtype=int32)

In [47]: result_array = np.array([np.arange(1, x+1) for x in na])

In [48]: result_array
Out[48]: array([array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

---

You can use list comprehension for your second usecase as well -

```
In [55]: new_arr = np.array([1,2,3])

In [56]: new_result_array = np.array([result_array * x for x in new_arr])

In [57]:

In [57]: new_result_array
Out[57]:
array([[array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]), array([2, 4, 6])],
       [array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]), array([3, 6, 9])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Ok; that make sense. In my edit I came up with a similar idea with "append" function, but yours seems to be simpler. Anyway, I am not sure how to proceed if I wanted to remove some elements from the nested at generation time. But I will work from this. Thanks

Comment: I think that some of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u could also help people. But there is one drawback to the method we came up with, it's that we can't do array multiplication element wise.