# How to get a subset of rows from a NumPy Matrix based on a condition?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How to return a set of rows of a NumPy Matrix that would match a given condition?

This is a Numpy Matrix object

```python
>>> X

matrix([['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
        ['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
        ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
        ['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
        ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
        ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

I would like to get the set of all rows that has the first column value as `'rainy'` so it tried this

```python
>>> X[X[:,0]=='rainy']

matrix([['rainy', 'rainy', 'rainy', 'rainy', 'rainy']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

But I wanted an output like this

```python
matrix([['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

How should this be done?

Comment: This is yet another reason not to use `np.matrix` - you're getting screwed over by `np.matrix`'s insistence on always being 2D.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for the info. But could you suggest an alternative NumPy structure that can handle string data but with the flexibility of a NumPy array class?

Comment: `numpy.array`, of course.

Comment: Well that worked like a charm! Thanks @user2357112; I didn't notice that `numpy.array` is suitable for strings too. That really does solve my problem. By the way, what is the use of `numpy.matrix` anyway while `numpy.array` is better? (Should I post this as another question in SO?)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u) for an explanation.  And note that since we now have @ for matrix multiplication in modern python, numpy matrices lost their one great syntactic advantage (multiplication syntax.)

Comment: [`numpy.matrix` exists for the sole purpose of making it easier to teach people who would be confused by the `.dot` syntax.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#transparent-syntax-is-especially-crucial-for-non-expert-programmers)

Comment: Wow! The matrix structure is present for just the pedagogical use case and code simplicity. Thanks for the info user2357112 and @DSM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> X[(X[:, 0] == 'rainy').ravel(), :]
matrix([['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

If you look at the result of your comparison:

```
>>> X[:, 0] == 'rainy'
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

This needs to be flattened into a vector using [ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
(X[:, 0] == 'rainy').ravel()
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

For additional constraints, this works:

```
X[(X[:, 0] == 'rainy').ravel() & (X[:, 1] == 'cool').ravel(), :]
matrix([['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
        ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Suppose, I would like to add an extra column constraint like `X[:,1]=='cool'`, where do I add it, Alex?

Comment: A rather complex implementation for something so simple (for Python, that is). Anyway, I can understand its because of the `numpy.matrix` class, so **answer accepted**! Thanks to the discussion with @user2357112, I'm switching over to `numpy.array` for a much simpler implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way of doing it.

```
foo = np.where(X[:, 0] == 'rainy') # get the index
X[foo, :]                          # The result you want.
```

Comment: Your answer works well for a single column constraint (completely covering my question). Could you expand a little for additional column constraints like `X[:,1]=='mild'`?