# Pythonicaly get a subset of rows from a numpy matrix based on a condition on each row and all columns

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following matrix,

```
In [0]: a = np.array([[1,2,9,4,2,5],[4,5,1,4,2,4],[2,3,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,4,3,6]])
Out[0]: 
array([[1, 2, 9, 4, 2, 5],
       [4, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 6]])
```

I want to get the indices of the rows that have 9 as a member. This is,

```
idx = [0,2]
```

Currently I am doing this,

```
def myf(x):
    if any(x==9):
        return True
    else:
        return False

aux = np.apply_along_axis(myf, axis=1, arr=a)
idx = np.where(aux)[0]
```

And I get the result I wanted.

```
In [1]: idx
Out[1]: array([0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

But this method is very slow (meaning maybe there is a faster way) and certainly not very *pythonic*.

How can I do this in a cleaner, more *pythonic* but mainly more efficient way?

Note that this question is close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206287/how-to-get-a-subset-of-rows-from-a-numpy-matrix-based-on-a-condition) but here I want to apply the condition on the entire row.

Comment: Use `(a==9).any(axis=1)` and then `np.where`.

Comment: A non-numPy solution would be something like `[index for index,row in enumerate(array) if 9 in row]` (result: `[0,2]`). I wonder if there'd be a speed difference, then.

Comment: @Divakar that's exactly what I was looking for. I was close actually, I tried but for some reason I was putting this after a`np.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine np.argwhere and np.any:

```
np.argwhere(np.any(a==9,axis=1))[:,0]
```

Comment: This is good, but still I think what @Divakar suggested in the comments is cleaner. Do you expect them to be equivalent performance wise?

Comment: @Divakar didn't write a complete solution but his approach would indeed be faster: `np.where((a==9).any(axis=1))[0]` on the sample matrix

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.argwhere` to find the indices where `a==9` and use the 0th column of those indices to index a:

```py
In [171]: a = np.array([[1,2,9,4,2,5],[4,5,1,4,2,4],[2,3,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,4,3,6]])
     ...: 
     ...: indices = np.argwhere(a==9)
     ...: a[indices[:,0]]
Out[171]: 
array([[1, 2, 9, 4, 2, 5],
       [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

...or if you just need the row numbers just save `indices[:,0]`.  If 9 can appear more than once per row and you don't want duplicate rows listed, you can use `np.unique` to filter your result (does nothing for this example):

```
In [173]: rows = indices[:,0]

In [174]: np.unique(rows)
Out[174]: array([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `np.nonzero` and `unique`

Check on `9`

```
np.unique((a == 9).nonzero()[0])

Out[356]: array([0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Check on `6`

```
np.unique((a == 6).nonzero()[0])

Out[358]: array([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Check on `8`

```
np.unique((a == 8).nonzero()[0])

Out[359]: array([2], dtype=int64)
```

On non-existent number, return empty list

```
np.unique((a == 88).nonzero()[0])

Out[360]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I follow but I think this is not getting the intended results. What I want is a list of all the rows in which my value occurs at least once. For `9` is `[0,2]`, for `6` is `[2,3]` and for `8` is `[2]`.

Comment: @myradio: ah, I misunderstood the question. I edited the answer with different method to get your desired output. Check my updated answer