# Is it possible to use einsum to transpose everything?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Ok, I know how to transpose a matrix, with for instance:

```
A = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
A.T
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20],
   [ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21],
   [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22],
   [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23],
   [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24]])
```

In the case of unidimensional arrays, it's not possible to use this ".T" tool (I don't know why, honestly) so to transpose a vector you have to change the paradigm and use, for instance:

```
B = np.arange(5) 
print B
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and because `B.T` would give the same result, we, applying this change of paradigm, use:

```
B[ :, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
   [1],
   [2],
   [3],
   [4]])
```

and I find this change of paradigm a little bit antiesthetic because a 1-D vector is in no way a different entity to a 2-D vector (a matrix), in the sense that mathematically speaking they come from the same family and share many things.

My question is: is it possible to do this tranposition with the (sometimes called) jewel of the crown of numpy that is einsum, in a more compact and unifying way for every kind of tensor? I know that for a matrix you do

```
np.einsum('ij->ji', A)
```

and you get, as previosuly with `A.T`:

```
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20],
   [ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21],
   [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22],
   [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23],
   [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24]])
```

is it possible to do it with 1-D arrays?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can transpose a 1D array using `einsum`

```
In [17]: B = np.arange(5)
In [35]: np.einsum('i,j->ji', np.ones(1), B)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.]])
```

but that isn't really what `einsum` is for, since `einsum` is computing a sum of products. As you might expect, it is slower than simply adding a new axis.

```
In [36]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j->ji', np.ones(1), B)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.43 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit B[:, None]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 230 ns per loop
```

---

If you are looking for a single syntax for transposing 1D or 2D arrays here are two options:

- Use `np.atleast_2d(b).T`:

  ```
  In [39]: np.atleast_2d(b).T
  Out[39]: 
  array([[0],
         [1],
         [2],
         [3],
         [4]])

  In [40]: A = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

  In [41]: np.atleast_2d(A).T
  Out[41]: 
  array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20],
         [ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21],
         [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22],
         [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23],
         [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24]])
  ```
- Use `np.matrix`:

  ```
  In [44]: np.matrix(B).T
  Out[44]: 
  matrix([[0],
          [1],
          [2],
          [3],
          [4]])

  In [45]: np.matrix(A).T
  Out[45]: 
  matrix([[ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20],
          [ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21],
          [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22],
          [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23],
          [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24]])
  ```

  A `matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray`. It is a specialized class which provides nice syntax for dealing with matrices and vectors. All matrix objects (both matrices and vectors) are 2-dimensional -- a vector is implemented as a 2D matrix with either a single column or a single row:

  ```
  In [47]: np.matrix(B).shape     # one row
  Out[47]: (1, 5)

  In [48]: np.matrix(B).T.shape   # one column
  Out[48]: (5, 1)
  ```

  There are other differences between `matrix`s and `ndarrays`s. The `*`
  operator computes matrix multiplication for `matrix`s, but performs
  element-wise multiplication for `ndarrays`. Be sure to [study the
  differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/190597) if you use
  `np.matrix`.

---

By the way, there is a certain beauty to the way NumPy defines transpose for `ndarrays`.
Remember that the `nd` in `ndarray` alludes to the fact that these objects can represent `N`-dimensional arrays. So whatever definition these objects use for `.T` must apply in `N` dimensions.

In particular, `.T` *reverses the order of the axes*.

In 2 dimensions, reversing the order of the axes coincides with matrix
transposition.  In 1 dimension, the transpose does nothing -- reversing the
order of a single axis returns the same axis. The beautiful part is that this
definition works in N-dimensions.

Comment: I agree with the beauty but that shouldn't have been the default behavior. It's basically annoying everyone who work exclusively in 2D in expense of impressing a very few working with N-D

Comment: That's actually worse than 1D arrays. But anyway nevermind

Comment: which you almost never transpose... I'm also doing applied math for living. This 1D business or matrix (which is discouraged by numpy themselves) is super annoying for all of us in the business

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the `np.matrix` seems very nice. I think that my problem was the apparent contradiction between the mathematical point of view of transposition and the python point of view.

Comment: @percusse - looks like you are coming from a MATLAB world.  In old MATLAB (e.g.3.0) EVERYTHING was 2d.  No dimensionless scalars, no 3d or larger, no cells or structures.  `numpy` has different roots.

Comment: @hpaulj Not quite but I see your point. The choice is very very programmer-like and unnatural. But they implemented matrix multiplication last year so who am I to say things are unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

The basic action of `einsum` is to iterate on all dimensions performing some sum of products.  It takes short cuts in a few cases, even returning views if it can.

But I think it will complain about 'i->j' or 'i->ij'.  You can't have indices on right that aren't already present on left.

`einsum('i,j->ji',A,[1])` or some variant, might work.  But it will be much slower.

```
In [19]: np.einsum('i,j->ij',[1,2,3],[1])
Out[19]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [30]: %%timeit x=np.arange(1000)
    ...: y=x[:,None]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 439 ns per loop

In [31]: %%timeit x=np.arange(1000)
    ...: np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,[1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.3 µs per loop
```