# How to multiply rows in matrices in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

My question is very intuitive in arrays but not in matrices. How can I multiple one element from row of one matrix in all equivalent row in other matrix. Let's assume I have:

```
x = np.matrix([[1], [2]])
y = np.matrix([[3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

and I want to get as a result:

```
[[3, 4], [10, 12]
```

or in a more readable way:

```
x = 1
    2

y = 3 4

    5 6
```

and I want to get as a result:

```
3 4

10 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** you can use [np.multiply()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) function:

```
In [57]: x
Out[57]:
matrix([[1],
        [2]])

In [58]: y
Out[58]:
matrix([[3, 4],
        [5, 6]])

In [59]: np.multiply(y, x)
Out[59]:
matrix([[ 3,  4],
        [10, 12]])
```

**OLD answer:**

it would work out of the box if you would use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`:

```
In [44]: xx = np.array([[1], [2]])

In [45]: yy = np.array([[3, 4], [5, 6]])

In [46]: xx
Out[46]:
array([[1],
       [2]])

In [47]: yy
Out[47]:
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [48]: yy * xx
Out[48]:
array([[ 3,  4],
       [10, 12]])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u) might help to understand the difference between `np.array` and `np.matrix`

Comment: I can't change the object... I need to know how to do it with matrices