# Can I calculate element-wise product using an np.matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I know I can do matrix multiplication using numpy arrays by using the `.dot` syntax. The regular `*` multiplication does element-wise multiplication.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print 'matrix multiplication', a.dot(a)
print 'element-wise multiplication', a * a

> matrix multiplication [[ 7 10]  [15 22]] 
> element-wise multiplication [[ 1  4]  [ 9 16]]
```

This works fine, but it's the opposite of all matrix operations I've ever learnt (i.e. the "dot product" is typically element-wise, and the regular product is typically a full matrix multiplication.)

So I'm investigating `np.matrix`. The nice thing is that matrix multiplication uses the `*` operator, but I'm to understand how to do element-wise multiplication.

```
m = np.matrix(a)
print 'matrix multiplication', m * m
print 'more matrix multiplication? ', m.dot(m)

> matrix multiplication [[ 7 10]  [15 22]] 
> more matrix multiplication?  [[ 7 10]  [15 22]]
```

I understand what's happening - there is not `.dot` operator for numpy matrix, so it falls through to the base `np.array` implementation. But does this mean that there's no way to calculate a dot product using `np.matrix`?

Is this just another argument for avoiding `np.matrix` and instead sticking with `np.array`?

Comment: Note that python 3.5 introduces the `a @ b` operator for matrix multiplication, if typing `a.dot(b)` frustrates you.

Comment: `.dot` is the tensor dot product.  As for _'"dot product" is typically element-wise'_ - can you find a reference for the meaning you assign to "dot product"? Are you reading matlab's `.*` as "dot product"?

Comment: @Kirk To answer your question on that comment: no, don't use matrices. Use arrays. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/525169) question.

Comment: @Eric no - don't have a reference apart from my memory of matrix algebra from school. I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get elementwise multiplication with the `multiply` function:

```
>>> np.multiply(m, m)
matrix([[ 1,  4],
        [ 9, 16]])
```

The result is the same for `np.multiply(a, a)`.

The name `dot` is indeed somewhat misleading, but the documentation for `np.dot` clearly says: "For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication".  Strictly speaking, the dot product is not defined for matrices; elementwise multiplication would be [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Dyadics_and_matrices).

Comment: Thanks! As someone who knows numpy well, do you recommend the array or matrix approach? Is there any benefit to using matrices?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: The time you actually need matrices is if you're using some non-numpy-aware third-party code that is only supposed to multiply scalars, and you want multiplication within that code to be a dot product.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: Well, it depends on what you're doing.  You would use matrices if you want to do matrix operations (like doing a lot of matrix multiplication).  If you're doing mostly vector operations (i.e., things that are row-based or column-based), arrays make more sense.

Comment: @BrenBarn: If you're doing lots of matrix multiplication, surely you just use the `@` matrix multiplication operator?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, if you're using Python 3.5, which not everyone is.

Answer (score 2):

The `np.dot` is consistent with the `dot product` (also called scalar product) for vectors

```
In [125]: np.arange(10).dot(np.arange(1,11))
Out[125]: 330
```

But `np.dot` is generalized to work with 2 (and higher) dimensional arrays.

MATLAB was built, from the start, on 2d matrices, and matrix product was seen as the most common and basic multiplication.  So the `.*` notation was used for element wise multiplication.  The `.` can also be used with `+` and other operators.

The basic structure in `numpy` is a n-d array.  Since such arrays can have 0,1,2 or more dimensions, the math operators were designed to work element wise.  `np.dot` was provided to handle the matrix product.  There's a variation called `np.tensordot`.  `np.einsum` uses Einstein notation (popular in physics).  A new `@` operator invokes the `np.matmul` function

```
In [131]: a.dot(a)
Out[131]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
In [134]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',a,a)
Out[134]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
In [135]: a@a
Out[135]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
In [136]: np.matmul(a,a)
Out[136]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

`np.matrix` is an `ndarray` subclass, and was added to make `numpy` more familiar to wayward MATLAB users.  Like old versions of MATLAB it can only be 2d. So results of `matrix` calculations will always be 2d (or scalar).  It's use is generally discouraged, though I'm sure it will be around for a long time.  (I use the `sparse` matrix more than `np.matrix`).

With the addition of the `@` operator there's one less reason to use `np.matrix`.

```
In [149]: m=np.matrix(a)
In [150]: m*m
Out[150]: 
matrix([[ 7, 10],
        [15, 22]])
In [151]: m@m
Out[151]: 
matrix([[ 7, 10],
        [15, 22]])
In [152]: m*m*m
Out[152]: 
matrix([[ 37,  54],
        [ 81, 118]])
In [153]: a@a@a
Out[153]: 
array([[ 37,  54],
       [ 81, 118]])
```