# Inconsistent numpy complex multiplication results

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

Consider the following Python code that multiplies two complex numbers:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix('28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j').astype(np.complex128)
b = np.matrix('-1.39818115e+09+1.39818115e+09j').astype(np.complex128)

#Verify values
print(a)
print(b)

c=np.dot(a.getT(),b)

#Verify product
print(c)
```

Now the product should be `-7.979228021897728000e+16 + 48j` which is correct when I run on Spyder. However, if I receive the values `a` and `b` from a sender to a receiver via MPI on an MPI4py program (I verify that they have been received correctly) the product is wrong and specifically `-7.97922801e+16+28534416.j`. In both cases I am using numpy 1.14.3 and Python 2.7.14. The only difference in the latter case is that prior to receiving the values I initialize the matrices with:

```
a = np.empty_like(np.matrix([[0]*(1) for i in range(1)])).astype(np.complex128)
b = np.empty_like(np.matrix([[0]*(1) for i in range(1)])).astype(np.complex128)
```

and then the function `MPI::Comm::Irecv()` gives them the correct values.

What is going wrong in the latter case if the `a` and `b` are correct but `c` is wrong? Is numpy arbitrarily setting the imaginary part since it's quite smaller than the real part of the product?

Comment: Would recommend changing from using `np.matrix()` to `np.array()`s first off and see if the behavior continues. The short of it: SciPy recommends using `ndarray`s, the long of it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/5087436. Also: "Is numpy arbitrarily setting the imaginary part since it's quite smaller than the real part of the product?" no. `complex128` in numpy are just stored as two separate 64-bit floats.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I replaced `np.matrix()` with `np.array()` and `getT()` with `transpose()` and it is still giving the same result in the MPI case. I even removed the `np.empty_like()` to see if this changes anything but no.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Any other suggestions? Please also note that the machine is the same in both cases. I am thinking of using sympy but as I remember from the past this was a bit slow for large matrix multiplications.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `np.empty_like()` in this example, why not just use `np.empty((1, 1), dtype=np.complex128)`? Either way, I'm going to guess that the junk values that get inserted into `np.empty()` are actually what is multiplying your number to give you not what you expect. Try initializing the array as zeros instead with `np.zeros()` and see if you end up with zeros. Why initialize at all anyways?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds The reason for initialization is that the received operands are n-by-n matrices in general and not just 1-by-1. Thus, the MPI needs to know that the receiver buffer is `complex128` and also preallocated. By the way, I also tried all of your suggestions but the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this doesn't address the `mp` stuff, but since it was raised in comments:

`np.matrix` can takes a string argument, and produce a numeric matrix from it.  Also notice that the shape is (1,1)

```
In [145]: a = np.matrix('28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j')
In [146]: a
Out[146]: matrix([[28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j]])
In [147]: a.dtype
Out[147]: dtype('complex128')
```

String input to `np.array` produces a string:

```
In [148]: a = np.array('28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j')
In [149]: a
Out[149]: array('28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j', dtype='<U36')
```

But omit the quotes and we get the complex array, with shape () (0d):

```
In [151]: a = np.array(28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j)
In [152]: a
Out[152]: array(28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j)
In [153]: a.dtype
Out[153]: dtype('complex128')
```

And the product of these values:

```
In [154]: b = np.array(-1.39818115e+09+1.39818115e+09j)
In [155]: a*b       # a.dot(b) same thing
Out[155]: (-7.979228021897728e+16+48j)
```

---

Without using `mp`, I assume the initialization and setting is something like this:

```
In [179]: x=np.empty_like(np.matrix([[0]*(1) for i in range(1)])).astype(np.complex128)
In [180]: x[:]=a
In [181]: x
Out[181]: matrix([[28534314.10478439+28534314.10478436j]])
In [182]: y=np.empty_like(np.matrix([[0]*(1) for i in range(1)])).astype(np.complex128)
In [183]: y[:]=b
In [184]: y
Out[184]: matrix([[-1.39818115e+09+1.39818115e+09j]])
In [185]: x*y
Out[185]: matrix([[-7.97922802e+16+48.j]])
```

It may be worth trying `np.zeros_like` instead of `np.empty_like`.  That will ensure the imaginary part is 0, instead of something random.  Then if the `mp` process is just setting the real part, you should get something different.