# Why is len(a[0]) different from a.shape[1]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix "a" that has the following properties:

> a.shape

(3, 220)

> a.shape[1]

220

> len(a)

3

> len(a[0])

1

> a[0].shape

(1, 220)

I don't get  why len(a[0]) is different from a.shape[1]. It seems like I can never access the subarray a[0]. Please help me to understand why that is the case. Thanks!

Comment: That's because you're using `numpy.matrix`. This is one of the reasons you shouldn't use `numpy.matrix`. Stop using `numpy.matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

Note, numpy recommends [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) that `np.matrix` should not be used, instead just use arrays:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

If you check out what `a[0]` is, you'll see the problem. Let's implement this in a smaller size so that it's easier to visualize:

```py
import numpy as np

# I'm using all zeros here for simplicity
y = np.matrix(np.zeros((5, 10)))

y.shape
(5, 10)

y[0]
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

`y[0]` is a *matrix* consisting of 1 row and 10 columns:

```py
y[0].shape
(1, 10)
```

If you use `np.array`, you avoid this problem altogether

```py
x = np.zeros((5, 10))

x.shape
(5, 10)

len(x[0])
10

x[0].shape
(10,)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [user2357112 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785608/why-is-lena0-different-from-a-shape1#comment103854219_58785608), the problem appears to be that you are using [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) instead of [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) (via [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)).

The Numpy documentation says the following about `matrix`:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

A regular Numpy array is [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151251) to a matrix, but can have any number of dimensions, and use the `@` operator instead of `*` to do matrix multipliation.