# what is the difference between as_matrix() and to_numpy() methods?

Tags: python, pandas, list

what is the difference between as_matrix() and to_numpy() methods?
I know that both are used to convert pandas dataframe into numpy ndarray, but what is the difference between these 2 methods?

Comment: One is deprecated, the other is not. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/4909087).

Answer (score 0):

I guess `as_matrix()` is confusing sometimes compared with Numpy metrix, then was deprecated. 
AS to what we get is `Numpy-array` from `.as_matrix()`, instead of `Numpy-matrix`. 
As for the defference bwt numpy narrays and nmpy matrices, hear is a good answer [by unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u).