# Numpy matrx and arrary simple calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do simple calculation on matricies and vector using np.array and np.matrix. My problem is that I do not know what is the difference between np.array and np.matrix. Calculation do I need to do is (among others):

```
A - matrix
B - matrix
x - vector
1. A * x
2. A * B
3. (A * A^T)^-1
```

Once, I need to do in using np.array and again using np.matrix.
I have tried many ways like:

```
Ax = A.dot(x)  # multiplication by vector
AB = np.dot(A, B) # multiplication by matrix
ab = np.matmul(A, B) # multiplication by matrix
At = A.transpose()
At = np.transpose(A)
inv = np.linalg.inv(a) # and inverse matrix, but I do not know which is np. matrix or np.array.
```

Kindly help.

Comment: you should provide an example of `A`, `B`, etc.

Comment: The task is that I do not have an example, I just have to know the difference on indifferent  A and B

Comment: `matrix` is deprecated, see the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

Comment: deprecated is not mean that it can not be used

Comment: What's wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: @hpauli I need to calculate multiplication, transpose and inversion in two ways, that is np.array and np.matrix and I do not now what is the difference and how to differ it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151251/14126301) clarifying the differences and the advantages of vectors and matrices.
It also explains multiplications between them.