# Identical matrices give different results based on how they're created

Tags: python, matrix, pagerank

I want to create a matrix with 1 column and n rows, to use in a calculation for a PageRank algorithm. If I make it like this, and then use the matrix in a calculation, it gives this result:

```
A = [[0.0375,0.4625,0.0375,0.32083333],
     [0.0375, 0.0375,0.0375,0.32083333],
     [0.8875, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.32083333],
     [0.0375, 0.4625, 0.8875, 0.0375]]
my_dp = 1/4

r = np.matrix([my_dp, my_dp, my_dp, my_dp])
r = np.transpose(r)
print(r)
for i in range(1,50):
    r = A*r
print("Final:", print(r))
```

```
[[0.25]
 [0.25]
 [0.25]
 [0.25]]
[[0.3570795 ]
 [0.19760835]
 [0.30663962]
 [0.13867253]]
Final: None
```

But if I create it automatically, using np.empty and .fill, I get this result:

```
r = np.empty(n)
r.fill(my_dp)
r = r[None].T
print(r)


for i in range(1,50):
    r = A*r
print("Final:", print(r))
```

```
[[0.25]
 [0.25]
 [0.25]
 [0.25]]
[[3.35329783e-71 3.35329783e-71 7.21422583e-04 9.73677480e-18]
 [1.60559016e-25 3.35329783e-71 3.35329783e-71 9.73677480e-18]
 [1.60559016e-25 7.21422583e-04 3.35329783e-71 3.35329783e-71]
 [1.60559016e-25 3.35329783e-71 3.35329783e-71 3.35329783e-71]]
Final: None
```

`A` is an nxn adjacency matrix.

Why is this? As you can see, if I print the matrices, they look identical, and they should be.

I tried creating a new matrix and filling it with .fill, I tried creating a matrix with .full, but everything resulted in the second outcome. The only time it works properly is when I create the matrix manually, which is not very possible, since to continue, I will need to have hundreds of elements in the matrix.

Comment: you haven't defined `A`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I have, it's just earlier in the code and I haven't included it here since it wouldn't really help. It's really just a nxn matrix.

Comment: it helps because otherwise your code cannot be copy pasted and ran for testing, which means that if we cannot run your code we will probably just skip the question and go to the next one.

Comment: For what it's worth, adding `A = np.ones((4,4))` duplicates this issue.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Okay, I have added the exact definition for A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clearly visible, but there IS a difference between the two examples.

The difference is that the first `r` is an `np.matrix`, and the second `r` is an `np.array`.  One of the few differences between the two is the multiply operator.  Using `*` on a matrix does a matrix multiply.  Using `*` on an array does an element-wise multiply, where `r` gets broadcast to fit the shape of `A`.

If you want a matrix multiply, use the `@` operator:

```
    r = A@r
```

[What are the differences between numpy arrays and matrices? Which one should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u)